# Burninate [stacking]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacking) tag looks like another good candidate for immolation:

- No wiki entry
- 89 questions, featuring a wildly eclectic mixture of web design, array manipulation, SQL, plotting etc.
- No followers

I can't imagine that anyone could consider themselves to be an expert in "stacking" in all of the senses that it's used here. There are already more descriptive tags that refer to specific uses, such as [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenation) for arrays etc.

Comment: Aren't we all experts in stacking up magic unicorn points here?

Comment: @Deduplicator the correct term is unicoins http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins

Comment: But I am stackin all day long, what should I do from now on?

Comment: Agreed, would be valid on Arcade subsite though. It's a fun [game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(video_game))!

Comment: You all make some good points - perhaps I'm wrong and the site is literally "overflowing" with stacking experts...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Burination completed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacking)

The tag no longer exists.

[image]