# Ban on the word "problem" for titles makes it difficult to edit existing posts

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter

Lately I tried to edit two posts in order to improve them. However, I wasn't allowed to save my edits, because the title contained the word "problem". So, I was forced to rephrase the title in order to be able to save my more relevant edits in the body of the post.

In one case the title was quite fine, so it was annoying to rephrase it in order to just get rid of the word "problem". I think that any edit on the title would not have improved it substantially.

In another case I was really doomed. I no longer remember the exact title, but take the following title as example: *What is an NP-complete problem?* In this case I don't see how to rephrase the title without asking a completely different question.

Is it really necessary to force an editor of an existing post to revise the title when it contains the word "problem"? Wouldn't it be better to ask the editor to revise the title, but to also give him the chance to ignore that request?

Comment: Don't even get me started.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I think the restriction is fine for new posts. I'm talking about editing existing posts.

Comment: What's the difference?  Why should "problem" be valid for old posts, but not for new ones or recently edited ones?

Comment: All the rules of asking new questions apply to edits as well. For eg, I had to rephrase titles containing 'problem' and copy entire code from JSFiddles into question while [burinating a tag recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268461/2982225). All current rules need to be followed to improve post quality.

Comment: @honk see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so#comment301322_114553) by [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

Comment: Ok, I see that this is actually intentional. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Simply use "feechure" instead.

Comment: Or case, challenge, knot, matter, nut, trouble, brainteaser, conundrum, poser, puzzle, quiz, riddle, stickler, stumper, toughie,  complication, difficulty, dilemma, disagreement, dispute, disputed point, doubt, Gordian knot, hard nut to crack, complication, crunch, disagreement, headache, hitch, holy mess, hot potato, hot water, issue, mess, obstacle, pickle, predicament, quandary, question, scrape, squeeze, trouble, worriment, enigma.

Comment: @HotLicks plz help withh programing hot water!!!

Comment: Although the OP is OK with the title word restriction for new posts, I would like to express my whole-hearted support for the restriction. It should even include 'newbe' and 'noob' as well.

Comment: I don't see any merit in making a distinction between new and edited posts. I do think there needs to be some way of overriding the restriction when typing a standard phrase, such "Traveling Salesman Problem" or "NP-complete problem". Any rephrasing to avoid the word "problem" will reduce the quality of the title. In particular, it may cause searches using the correct technical term to miss.

Comment: And, in those cases where "problem" really does belong, simply misspell it.  (You get the added bennie of frustrating all those point-seeking editors who go around correcting minor spelling proble... er, errors.)

Comment: @HotLicks That does create a dependency on search engines guessing correctly about what was really meant, so that they will hit on "traveling salesman probem" when searching for "traveling salesman problem". I suspect other hits with the correct spelling will be shown first. It seems to me that SO is shooting itself in the foot by prohibiting correct terminology in titles.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Well, only maybe 40% of SO titles are reasonably accurate and specific to begin with.

Comment: I tend to take the attitude that "SO let the title into the system; if they want the posts improved and also want to force me to edit the title, then they can pay me for the privilege.  Until I'm paid, I don't bother editing posts with titles that will cause me problems as the editor."  I've abandoned otherwise good and even necessary edits because of this.  Not always, but sometimes, and these days, I usually don't get started on the edit because I realize that I will have to fix the title and I don't think it needs fixing.

Comment: "What does NP-Complete mean" seem to be immediate candidate for closing as off-topic to me... Same for other mentioned higher level problems. [CS.se] or [programmers.se] may be better place for such explanations and no need for "problem" on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov A question about a program for approximating TSP could be on-topic for SO.

Comment: Related posts on Meta.SE: [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107989/159251) and [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944/159251)

Comment: What's the pr0blem?

Comment: Best part of having our own Meta: stupid policies like this get some more daylight.

Comment: We don't have PROBLEMS! We have OPPORTUNITIES!!!!!

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: That also sounds more positive. Traveling Salesman Opportunity sounds not so much like work, but more like profitable business ;)

Comment: Try to change "problem" to "prоblеm".

Comment: @bob it's a great halting opportunity when google has no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 5):

I've been tripped up by this a few times.

Every time I get tripped up by it, It reminds me that I should make my edits more expansive.

There are a few instances (like the one you mention) where 'problem' *could* be relevant, but I think those are so few and far between that even they can be worked around -- and it can improve the question, to boot!

For your case:

> What is an NP-complete problem?

A good edit would be:

> What does NP-complete mean? How can something be defined as NP-Complete?

Comment: Is your example even on-topic?

Comment: @bjb568: A post with the original title actually exists on SO. But you can also think of questions on any *problem* in computational complexity: *travelling salesman problem*, *knapsack problem*, etc.

Comment: @George Stocker: Ok, I get the idea: I have to keep my head spinning. I also have to admit that nobody told me that editing posts has (always) to be easy ;)

Comment: “It reminds me that I should make my edits more expansive.” Why should I be forced to do this? I spend my free time trying to improve the site, and then the site tells me “You're not doing enough!” I believe that small improvements are okay, that's what crowd-sourcing is good at. When I improve punctuation of a Wikipedia article, I'm not forced to fix all the [citation needed] in that article. I don't see why SO should be different in this regard.

Comment: "`What is the definition of NP-complete?`" And no, I don't think it's on-topic. There's still a cs-site, right?

Comment: @svick It is because edits are peer reviewed with multiple users, if the edit is very small, the total time spent on reviewing is more than the time spent on editing, which makes it unfeasible.

Comment: @UmurKontacı The user you're responding to has more than 80K rep, and does not need their edits reviewed.

Comment: Mr. Atwood's take on this in a *slightly* different context: http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/

Answer (score 4):

<strike>At the moment it appears that you can outsmart the filter by injecting a zero width character into the middle of the word pro​blem.  I tested using a [ZWNJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) and a [ZWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) and it removed the error about problem not being allowed from the editor.  This probably shouldn't happen; but is unlikely enough to become a problem that I suggest delaying the implementation of a fix until Nevember 32nd (sic).</strike>

I just tested this to see if it would affect search.  It does: A question title with "prob`ZWNJ`lem" no longer shows up if you search for "problem".  More seriously, after I saved the question the ZWNJ was converted into a space, so it failed aesthetically too.

Disclaimer:  No questions were permanently harmed in the course of this test.  Upon conclusion a non-problematic title was provided in payment.

Answer (score -10):

Even in the odd case that a word is proper, there are plenty of synonyms in the english language to circumvent it.

So you could do a few word swaps!

`s/problem/issue/i`

:D

Comment: Ah yes, the good old Halting Pickle.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Halting Pickle? Say what now?

Comment: It's an obstructionist cucumber.

Comment: There's also the Knapsack Predicament.

Comment: Stahp I don't get it D:

Comment: The [Traveling Salesman Botheration](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: @Josh They all sound like Big Bang Theory episode titles.

Comment: The "Traveling Salesman Issue" is now calling for abstracts.

Comment: That was The Knapsack Predicament! Up next on stage, get ready to rock with Halting Pickle!

Comment: The day meta became reddit, in a good way.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - in the US (and perhaps elsewhere) "pickle" is a slang synonym for "problem", often used in the construction "in a pickle", e.g.: "The singer found herself in a pickle when her costume's seam gave way during a particularly energetic number, but the audience loved it".

Comment: @neminem: I think I knew the drummer for Halting Pickle. Wasn't he the one that ended up as a burned out druggie, living on a ranch somewhere out in the Valley with his messed up girlfriend and two old cows? And some cattle, too, I think..?