# Bug with words not allowed in titles?

Tags: support, questions, title

I edited the question [Question about specific lines in a .DPROJ file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703225/question-about-specific-lines-in-a-dproj-file) and when clicking 'Save' I got the error that the word *Question* was not allowed in the title (it's now gone of course).

How did it get in there in the first place?
Does anything need repairing?

Comment: It's an old question, it is likely that those restrictions were put in place after it was asked.

Comment: Likely the question was posted with that title before the rule banning it was introduced

Comment: Ah, its from 2009. Is this meta question worth keeping (I suggest a proper answer that I can vote on) or do I delete it?

Comment: That's up to you, but I might suggest reading [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268546/3419894). I don't think it's a duplicate, but is certainly related. That said, this probably is a duplicate of *something*, but keeping this question around may not be a bad thing if it's easier to find.

Comment: Ah, thanks @JonK, that was the post I was just looking for.

Comment: _Does anything need repairing?_... The title I guess :-)

Comment: Aha! Cross site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114221/263482 - again though, probably doesn't hurt to keep this around as a marker

Comment: It was a good clue to change the title to something more descriptive. Simply removing the word "question" didn't make much difference, it is still a poor title. And why didn't you remove the "thank you" while you were editing?

Comment: @Cody Because I'm human and I miss things ;-) Actually it is a matter of focus. I noticed the dead link so fixed that only. Then I had to quickly change the title to get my correction accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was asked back in 2009:

> asked Nov 9 '09 at 19:34

way, *way*, **way** before the script that blocks certain words in titles was introduced.

Comment: I've been trying to find out exactly *when* this rule was introduced, and if there's a list of banned words in question titles, but my Google-fu is failing me. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: @JonK - There is a list, but I'm fairly sure it's not available to moderators. The "list of feature changes" question on MSE should have this in.