# I thought we blocked the words "need help" from titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, title, quality-filter

I just ran into this creature :

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

what bugs me is that I was pretty sure Meta had decided to block the phrase "need help" from posts.

Doesn't this just make you *cringe* though ? reading sounds terrible

This is just "Discussion-y" (ie rant ), I'm not expecting anything concrete here

Comment: I guess *this* question should have been blocked, too... ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - ha,well... mondays  !

Comment: I'm just ranting because of the caffeine

Comment: Is this a better title? "Conway's Game of Life Java- Want assistance getting started" Because that's what filtering the phrase "need help" will lead to (at best).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Ok, let's see though . Wasn't the point of blocking the "need help" phrase to deter people from giving us vague posts?  I get your point though, I dunno - block "Want assistance" too : \  ugh it is mess

Comment: As discussed in [Ban on the word “problem” for titles makes it difficult to edit existing posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268546), it's trivially easy to circumvent filters without improving the quality of your post. Instead of "help", people could use "advice", "assistance", "h3lp", "a hand", or one of a zillion other equally useless words or phrases.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Ok understood , it's clear now . Well, the reliable human must be watchful then :-) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: And to remain watchful, the reliable human must consume ample quantities of Coffee...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  - :-) Indeed indeed,  hmm still 3:00 PM? Ok another cup !!!

Comment: I assume that this 'question' has been burninated by now.