# Banning 'problem' in questions creates false positives on named concepts

Tags: discussion, title

The "diamond problem" refers to a particular concept in languages like C++ that support multiple inheritance. This isn't the case of someone using lazy terminology in describing their question - in fact, the OP is being quite precise. In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268546/ban-on-the-word-problem-for-titles-makes-it-difficult-to-edit-existing-posts), the same issue is pointed out for questions mentioning "NP-complete problems" and the "traveling salesman problem".

I understand that the word 'problem' in question titles is often problematic, but the blanket ban on it creates false positives when dealing with concepts that contain "problem" in their name. I see great justification that the filter is generally useful from [actual data on questions blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter), but no response whatsoever to the false positives it's created.

Here's a general list of cases where this comes up

- [Diamond problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534945/diamond-p-roblem-with-only-1-virtual-inheritance)
- [Slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) (>200 up-votes on question and answer)
- [Expression problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596366/what-is-the-expression-problem)
- [Halting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111155/what-exactly-is-the-halting-problem)
- [NP-Complete problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141779/solving-the-np-complete-problem-in-xkcd) (and really, problems in any complexity class)
- [Traveling-Salesman problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268546/ban-on-the-word-problem-for-titles-makes-it-difficult-to-edit-existing-posts) (and other specific computational starting points that one wishes to solve - Knapsack, makespan, etc)
- N-body problem
- Monty Hall problem

Others are welcome to suggest more here.

Comment: See also: [Remove blacklist filter for "problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110789), [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107989), and [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944)

Comment: It seems http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter answered the value of this feature for true positives. What's missing in all of the official responses is any sign of even marginal concern for the false positives, in which 'problem' is an integral part of the name of the concept in question.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I think my edit should make it clear that this is specifically about the issue of false positives for the filter that has gone wholly unaddressed.

Comment: This has been addressed many times. Read the links in Josh Caswell's comment. It's not going to be changed. For every legitimate use of the word "problem" in a title, people created 1000 questions with the title "help me with my problem." The true positives far outweigh the false positives. The filter is working as designed.

Comment: @Novelocrat That doesn't make your post not a duplicate.

Comment: In the narrow sense that none of the existing posts are focused on the false positives, I might even dispute that. Most of them focus on the annoyance of having to edit out "problem" when fixing other problems, with FPs as an aside at best, or unmentioned at worst.

Comment: @Novelocrat the *real* question is does the filter help create better answers and reduce the noise seen on the front page from poorly worded question titles? If the answer to this question is 'yes', then the difficulty about writing a question about the the [three body problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586195/) or the [monty hall problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213882/) is one that takes a bit more creativity from the asker - not an insurmountable problem itself.

Comment: That's *not* the real question. I've already stipulated that the filter, in general, vastly improves question title quality, and linked to the data used to support exactly that proposition.  The real question is whether forcing the rare cases where using the word "problem" in a question title is good for quality not to use it can be mitigated, how to implement those mitigations, and whether they're worthwhile.

Comment: There's a proposal somewhere for a whitelist that would allow proper-name problems like "Halting Problem"; I can't find it at the moment. That would solve the whole thing as far as I can see.