# Why are vague pleas for help still allowed in the question title?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, title

Take a look at the heading of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584443/please-help-me-to-put-a-loop-here-i-dont-know-where-can-i-put-the-loop-please-s) ([screenshot for the < 10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6VO3.png) and the [full revision history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywrR6.png) and [timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJFDt.png)). The heading includes phrases like:
'Please someone help me;'
'Please help me'

---

How is it that such kind of phrases are allowed but phrases like 'problem with' (as far as I remember) aren't?

Comment: See [What triggers my title rejection?](/q/373415/4642212). The title is longer than 40 characters.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Does that mean that, I can simply add garbled text in the title and get around the constraint?!

Comment: @kesarling yes. And some do. I saw one yesterday that just had `svsvsvsv` appended at the end

Comment: @VLAZ. if we take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373459/11930602) answer, it mentions that in 2011, some words got completely banned from titles of all length. Why can't we simply include such words (or even phrases for that matter) in that list?

Comment: @VLAZ, ain't it high time now to update the regex?

Comment: @kesarling with the amount of [problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275204/banning-problem-in-questions-creates-false-positives-on-named-concepts) (lot's of similar questions) the current implementation has, I would say that a more restrictive regex would not be great.

Comment: Meta information in posts is a minor problem (but should be removed). More worrying is that a person like this, exhibiting extreme sloppiness, will soon be trusted with developing critical systems (economical, safety, etc.).

Comment: @PeterMortensen we all have to start somewhere, discipline is not passed to you from the womb unfortunately. If I would be able to go back in time and talk to my 20 year younger self, I'd punch me in the face.

Comment: Ironically this question could use a better title...

Comment: There's *all kinds* of low hanging fruit they could hit with this for question title regexes and body regexes, but they have other priorities, it seems, than maintaining high-quality content enforcement.

Comment: The sad part is that people expect begging for help to get them some mercy, when the opposite actually occurs.

Comment: think this is the price we pay for [abandoned Triage implementation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601). If it was completed, stuff like that would be hidden from you and kept in "purgatory" until either improved or deleted. I studied ([skipped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409089/provide-an-option-to-filter-the-triage-queue-by-tags#comment854177_409089)) probably few thousands questions that went to triage and I can assure you that system detects and dispatches such issues very quickly and correctly... quite a pity that the rest of this feature fails to do the job

Comment: @rene you'd better post timeline screenshot to help readers see if this question was detected by triage heuristics or not (revisions history misses details like that)

Comment: ...just as I guessed, [timeline screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJFDt.png) shows that system immediately detected post as troublesome ("17 hours ago") and correctly pushed it to Triage queue. It is so sad that this didn't make any real difference

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why are vague pleas for help still allowed in the question title?
>
> How is it that phrases like: 'Please someone help me' and
> 'Please help me' are allowed but phrases like 'problem with' aren't?

Neither are allowed according to the community norms.  But just because something is not allowed doesn't mean you can physically prevent it from happening.

Consider the following analogy:

Where I live the State Government places a limit of 50 kph speed limit on suburban roads (unless signposted otherwise).  Speeding is not allowed.  But it cannot be prevented ... because it is impractical to put speed limiters on every car, truck, motorcycle and bicycle.  So we have police officers set up radar cameras ... and fines to **deter** people from breaking the speed limit.

It is the same with bad question titles on Stack Overflow.  We don't accept them.  But we can't prevent them because we (or more precisely, Stack Exchange) don't have a technological solution that can **reliably** distinguish between acceptable and unacceptable titles.

What we do have is a lame mechanism involving regexes that filters out **some** of the most egregiously bad stuff.  But no amount of polishing the regexes is going to prevent people from entering bad question titles.  You can't solve this problem with regexes.  It is a gnarly problem in English parsing and semantic analysis.  (There are probably a few PhDs in it ...)

---

Fortunately we have do other mechanisms, albeit labor-intensive ones; i.e. editing titles on the OP's behalf, downvoting (deterrence) and voting to close.

And as [Martin James noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410490/63550), many folks around here treat a badly written title as a quick way to filter out the (presumably) bad questions.  So people who can't be bothered to write a sensible title for their questions are diminishing their chances in getting help.

Comment: Thanks man! This is exactly the kind of answer that was needed. To the point and succinct!

Comment: "editing titles on the OP's behalf" funny because this very question was edited too :D

Answer (score 41):

> How is it that such kind of phrases are allowed but phrases like 'problem with' (as far as I remember) aren't?

In a knowledge base of questions and answers such phrases don't belong in titles. Period.

The [Pr0blam title filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so) is somehow a feature SE can't find the off-switch for. When that is gone all titles are allowed. And they should.

What is lacking is an effective and successful way to get proper guidance in front of askers what criteria their post, tags and title should conform to. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is probably one of the few "interaction" sites found on the internet where content matters. The expectation is: *Here is a textbox, I can put anything I want here just like on all other sites that resemble a forum.*

But lacking that effective way to get new contributors to read, understand and abide by the few basic rules laid out in the Help center, all we can do is fix after the fact. That is how we rock here. So it is a bit disappointing that an editor did fix the body of the post but didn't touch the title. In the same way it is disappointing that you didn't suggest an edit to fix the title either. I give you that you might be blocked due to the review queue being full. Equally disturbing is the fact that no other viewer took on that title.

Stack Overflow is community curated site.  You can fix any content that has issues, and you should. Don't rely on an under-staffed developer team to implement crazy AI (*cough* regex) to fix parts of human created content that is better curated by a human, especially when you probably need to fix more than just the title.

Anyway, I polished that specific turd for you. Could as well have close-voted it.

To make my point: These phrases are (still) allowed because no filtering / blocking / clever stuff is implemented and the one case that was implemented turned out so harmful that no new attempts to disallow these phrases upfront should be made. Proper, on time and context-sensitive guidance for the asker and aggressive editing after the fact by everyone is the best advice going forward.

To explicitly answer the question:

Why is it so? Because no one asked for it and we're glad no-one did ... oh wait ... [Should we forbid “please help me” titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145477/should-we-forbid-please-help-me-titles)

And for why we shouldn't implement what you suggested I quote [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145481):

> straight-up blocks haven't been, um, terribly productive. I, for one, don't fancy seeing more titles of the form, "Plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz HALP!"

Comment: Succinct. Excellent! It could be FAQ material.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that the OP here asked someone else to fix that. They simply asked why those phrases aren't included in the ban list, which this does not answer at all. Your trite rant about content and editing in general is somewhat appropriate to the question, but the holier-than-thou attitude and the "Just do your job and shut up!" ending are flat out despicable.

Comment: Why, rene? Why do you polish help vampire turds?

Comment: @IanKemp I had this type of answer in mind but assumed the question had more substance. When I was done writing the question turned out to be unsalvageable.  So I quickly turned this answer into a rant to please everyone and then quickly moved on to the next meta challenge.  You can't win everyday. I'm not that good.

Comment: @MikeM. that are awesome points. Mind putting them in an answer so the OP has something to accept instead of having to live with my despicable rant.

Comment: This seems to miss the point OP is trying to argue, which is that we should be fixing this problem *before the content is posted* rather than relying on established users with edit privileges to see and fix content.

Comment: Nothing that I said constitutes an answer to this question. I realize that you might be reacting emotionally there, as was I when I first commented, and I apologize for that. I should've offered my opinions much more diplomatically. However, if you don't see how your last paragraph, at least, is a little over-the-top then I'm afraid that we're just at odds fundamentally (which is no big deal really; it just means that we can't ever hang out together). Cheers!

Comment: "You can fix any content that has issues, and you should." sadly, some users have taken upon themselves to make sure that no one improves the questions because "it goes against author intent". Author intent sucks most of the time.

Comment: Emotionally as opposed to logically, people. I did not mean to imply anything about anyone's emotional state otherwise.

Comment: @MikeM. [spot on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410459/why-are-vague-unspecific-pleas-for-help-still-allowed-in-the-question-title/410461#comment857966_410461). While the answer does satisfactorily answer what the current situation is and a little why it is so, it does not answer why it shouldn't be the way I "suggested"

Comment: *the one case that was implemented turned out so harmful*... someone please elaborate :)

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him If you want a friendly, non-ranty answer, write a better question and do more about the problem than complain. Frankly, your original question wasn't much better than the ones you complained about.

Comment: @jpmc26, sure! How would you have written the original question (which frankly was just a one-liner)?

Comment: Also, I never complained about the question, but rather about the system which allowed such a question to go unfiltered in the first place :/

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I'm not going to sink an hour into rewriting a question that's already received drastic improvement, but if I had written it, I certainly would have put enough effort in to give it more than a single line's worth of substance. If you knew that was the quality of what you were posting, you shouldn't have posted it.

Comment: No, that was not what I meant. The [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410459/why-are-vague-unspecific-pleas-for-help-still-allowed-in-the-question-title#comment858098_410461) was rhetorical. There literally could not have been any better way than that, for usually the simplest way is the best. :D (The title did need a little work though, that I accept)

Answer (score 1):

It saves time and effort for curators.  Scan title, immediately decide to downvote and close irrespective of body content, open, downvote, close/delete, move on to the next question that might be more worthy of the limited volunteer time available.

Comment: I am just gonna say it. I have never seen a vote count *that* balanced

Comment: No chicanery on my part, it just turned out that way:)  I guess that some think that 'Can you help me' titles are not rude/abusive.  Such OP should try such requests on their doctor, accountant, lawyer or garage technician and see what happens to their bills.  When they are living in a cardboard box because they have lost their house, they would have plenty of time to consider how not to waste the time, volunteered or paid, of professionals.