# How to effectively ban "is it possible"/"is there a way"?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Can we get some form of a warning/low post flag posts with "is it possible"/"is there a way" in the body or title? 99% of the time it is something that is possible, but the question is generally too broad or asking for a recommendation.

Comment: So you mean to ask *Is it possible to ban “is it possible”?*

Comment: @BhargavRao yep. On meta it's more appropriate

Comment: I think the rest of the question would dictate the quality of the post. Simply having the phrase "is it possible" doesn't immediately mark the post as troublesome.

Comment: Blocking specific wording [has proven to be p0rblematic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268546/ban-on-the-word-problem-for-titles-makes-it-difficult-to-edit-existing-posts).

Answer (score 6):

Using the text "is it possible" does not affect the content of the post. It may be an indicator to use for post quality, but upon some inspection

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22is%20it%20possible%22

[image]

The phrase really doesn't seem to negatively affect posts. I believe the premise that "is it possible" being used causes bad questions is flawed and see no support in favor of that point of view.

Comment: most of those top questions are more than 5 years old.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Did you look at all 300,000 matches? You have to go at least 300 matches in to even get to a post with less than 100 votes.

Comment: Here is an example from page 100 of the search (as in 5000 matches in). It was from 3 weeks ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916131/how-to-define-a-part-of-class-name-as-macro Doesn't seem low quality to me.

Comment: Note that for the majority (granted, not all) of those questions they would be made better (without really changing their content) by editing them from, "Is it possible to do X?" to, "How do I do X?"  It's not enough of a problem to prevent the question from being good before such an edit (hence why I don't support the proposal) but it would still be better to make that change.

Comment: @Servy - How do I define a class name like FooBar. Is it possible to define a class with a name like FooBar? Not much of a difference.

Comment: @TravisJ So...what's your point?  I would consider both questions to be low quality questions (what did you try to do to name a class like `FooBar` and why didn't it work)?  That said, if both questions provided and attempt and a problem (so I could see why they were struggling to name a class like `FooBar`) both would be acceptable questions, and the former would be better (as someone asking the latter almost certainly means the former).

Comment: @Servy - My point was that editing it to How do I from Is it possible isn't going to make much difference - It is all about what else accompanies the phrase. Also, I am talking more about a post containing this text. Did you see the example I posted in my comment above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916131/how-to-define-a-part-of-class-name-as-macro? That was the context for my comment (sorry for not posting enough information at the time).  In that context, they do provide what does work, what would ideally work, and gave some code and situational explanations.

Comment: @TravisJ I didn't say that the question would be *unacceptable* without such an edit.  The edit does improve it.  Basically that example, along with most every other case like it, involves everyone reading the question to pretend that they asked, "How do I do X?" even though they didn't.  It's not like anyone just says, "No, it's not possible" or "yes, it's possible" as answers.  Rather than forcing everyone to pretend the question is asking "How" and not "Can I" you can just edit the question.  It's virtually always what is *meant* by the question.

Comment: @Servy - You make good points, but I think this is probably getting too nuanced to discuss.

Answer (score 4):

We don't really need to ban it.  It's easy enough to just edit such posts from "Can I do X" to "How do I do X?", given that that's what is virtually always being asked.  Some of these questions will be too broad, some won't.  If they are, close them as appropriate.

An actual ban is a problem both because many of the questions just need to be rephrased, not closed or deleted, and also because there will be false positives where that phrase is used at some point in the question without it being the fundamental question being asked.