# Increase reputation requirement for triage

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage, privileges

The bar needs to be raised for triage reviewers.

Inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8168973

[image]

By the many users (such as the one unsalvageable vote shown) who get disputed flags from this queue, and also by the amount of "should be improved" that seems to erroneously enter the Help and Improvement queue.

Right now, there are only 11 triage reviews available, which is really low considering the amount of questions posted to Stack Overflow at a constant rate. This means that the demand for triage reviews is low enough that the supply can be slightly limited without affecting the queue.

The access to review queues privilege was created a long time ago when the overall flow of reviewing was much different. It now makes sense to tie this review queue to a different privilege.

Specifically, this one

[image]

The reason being that if users cannot decide whether a post is off topic or not (which seems kind of clear given the current situation of triage) then they should not be reviewing questions to determine if they are off topic or not.

Here are a few more examples, they were just from a single random page in the review history

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8169433 Note the one unsalvageable vote is from a higher rep user who probably got a disputed flag
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8169385 Note the lack of knowing about close reasons, and as a result no close votes (there were no 3k+ users)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8169462 Same as the previous bullet point

Comment: More/better audits can also help with this.  Keep in mind that it's been shown that reputation tends to have almost no correlation with review quality once you pass very low thresholds.  Plenty of the bad reviewers have lots of rep.  (Not that I'm opposed to this, I'm not, just saying it's probably not going to be *sufficient*.)

Comment: @Servy - Perhaps it would be interesting to see some numbers on the correlation between audit failures and reputation.

Comment: I would suggest a 2K rep for triage as if we you are being allowed to edit anything then you should be able to triage.  That said I have seen 3K and 4K user picking should be improved instead of unsalvageable.  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8165473

Comment: *get declined flags from this queue* **yes**!

Comment: If we make the requirement 3k I hope that it won't cut away from the number of reviewers in the CV queue.

Comment: @Rizier123 That would be bad for me.  I have 85 disputed flags and I think all of them come from triage

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you read my comment wrong, I mean "yes", like yes I get also many disputed flags from the queue even if  as in the example the posts are just crap. And that needs to end!

Comment: @Rizier123 Ah I see.  Travis said people get declined flags in his post that you quoted.  I edited the post to change it to disputed.

Comment: They get disputed, because 95% of those guys, know nothing or next to nothing about the language it was programmed in. Hence, some of my disputed flags. I think I know what I'm talking about when I flag something. I don't flag something just to make pretty bubbles.

Comment: I think even at a higher privilege, the given example would still be disputed from time to time. It could be turned into a more useful question by substituting "is it possible" with "how can i". Still a poor question, but certainly valid and answerable, and wouldn't require the OP's input to make such an edit.

Comment: @Servy - Will audits even help, if the core problem is that [no one seems to know what "Should Be Improved" even means?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button)

Comment: I on the other hand, had thought up an idea a few weeks ago, where a certain amount of reputation on a given tag would be required in order to really dispute a flag. If say for instance, someone only had 50 in PHP, then that doesn't really give them enough credibility to reject a flag, as opposed to let's say 250/500. I'm just thinking outloud here, of course.

Comment: Maybe those higher reps ran out of close votes and in despair started voting *should be improved*....

Comment: @BradLarson If people keep failing audits for saying that really terrible questions Should Be Improved, hopefully they'll stop saying that really bad question Should Be Improved.  Now, I think it'd be great if this was done in addition to renaming it, improving the written guidelines, etc. but at the end of the day people don't read things.  I'm very much of the "do all of the things that can help" approach though, rather than trying to find one magic solution that fixes everything.  I'm very pro-improved direction as well as pro-better audits.

Comment: @KevinB - In your opinion, "How can I make a script to remove responses from a spreadsheet that are over 3 weeks old" without any other context at all, just that one line, is a valid question to post?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be. But, in this case, it has tags which make it clear what the question is asking for. Google apps scripts in google spreadsheets are scripts that can be used on a spreadsheet to manipulate it's contents, and often come in the form of plugins that you can add to your spreadsheet.

Comment: @KevinB - The tag alone isn't enough context. It still doesn't relate any part of the problem such as the composition the OP is working with or what subset of their problem is actually what they are having an issue with. It may be clear that the question is asking for an entire tutorial, but that doesn't make it a valid question.

Comment: I of course disagree, I think it's plenty of context, and an answer to such a question could be useful to more people than, say, your every day my code is broken with this error questions.

Comment: @KevinB - A single line of text requesting a full feature implementation is most definitely not on topic. I am not sure where you are deriving this belief from.

Comment: I think more along the lines of the many examples provided here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294420/how-to-effectively-ban-is-it-possible-is-there-a-way

Comment: @KevinB - I don't see any full features there, nor full implementation. "Is there a ternary operator in python" or similar are slightly less scoped. I understand what you are getting at though. I think that type of question when narrowed is on topic (and that set is a good example of on topic versions if it). It just becomes a little egregious when they ask for a full plugin.

Comment: How many known-bad Triage audits will fail you if you hit Should Be Improved? I know there are some known-good audits that will *not* fail you if you choose SBI, but I don't hit SBI very often on audits so I'm not sure about the inverse.

Comment: For clarity, are you now suggesting raising FP and LA thresholds as well? Triage was not added to the access review queues privilege "a long time ago".

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I think you are taking this personally because it affects you (you are on the top list of review counts). I did not say triage was added to the privilege a long time ago. You are attempting to take my post out of context, just as your answer does. I merely said the privilege for access to the review queue at 500 reputation has been around for a long time. The point was that grouping triage into this privilege should be reconsidered. I think it makes more sense to be grouped with the closure privilege. Perhaps you can make an argument for 2000 reputation and the edit privilege.

Comment: @TravisJ: Mm, possibly. I certainly consider from personal experience that this is unnecessary, but I also am not convinced by the logical consistency of your arguments; you're not distinguishing Triage from other review queues other than a single anecdotal example and a vague handwave at disputed flags. I sympathize with the latter  (160+/200 of my disputed flags are from Triage, after all), but it's not enough to build a solid argument on, especially not for your specific proposed solution.

Comment: @TravisJ: If anything, I actually would be more open to raising the threshold for FP and LA; [they are not trivial queues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), and learning on Triage, where *nothing is final* and *multiple reviewers are required for any action*, is arguably a far better flow.

Comment: I don't think reputation and review quality are actually related. At least when I go through my disputed Triage flags, I see plenty of higher rep users (3K+) voting "should be improved" on unsalvageable questions.

Comment: Why is everyone going on about "needs improvement" when a more serious issue is all the "looks OK" votes on junk questions?

Comment: Nah, Triage should stay where it is. First Posts and Late answers should be unlocked at 750 rep.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Most reviewers are probably following the instructions in the review queue to the letter:

[image: Triage instructions]

Almost *anything* can be edited by the author into something that is clear and answerable, and so, many reviewers send almost everything to the Help & Improvement queue. I know, I did so too until the H&I queue was revealed.

Those of us who follow Meta SO regularly know by now, through a number of different threads, that this is not what you're *supposed* to do. The vast majority of the reviewers though, are unlikely to follow the discussions on Meta if they even know of its existence.

There have been a number of feature requests regarding this problem:

- [Rephrase Triage help text for "Should be improved" and "Unsalvageable "](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable)
- [Suggestion for rewording of triage review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance)
- [Please rename the "Should be improved" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button)
- [Add Flowchart in Triage Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289817/add-flowchart-in-triage-review)

In light of this, I think this discussion about reputation is mostly pointless. If anything, it is the instructions *in the review queue* that need to change.

Comment: Ideally, there would need to be one more option;  break apart "should be improved" into two categories;  "should be improved by author," and "can be improved by community."  I run into this a bit.  In most cases it is the former, however in others it just needs some formatting to read.  If they fall under the former, they should automatically go into the close queue if they are not improved without a significant amount of time;  this would reduce the workload for those reviewing these.

Answer (score 49):

[Reputation is irrelevant in the face of reviews.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293789/1079354)  You're not going to ensure more accuracy or that more questions that are in triage ultimately make their way into the right buckets if the reputation is increased.  The data there is very mixed, and I can't draw a direct correlation between accuracy of votes and user reputation.

Further, there's a tendency for users with higher reputation (except that wonderful outlier at 20K) to do *less* of these reviews.  This isn't exactly something that a handful of users should only ever do; it should be available to as many as reasonably possible.

The *real* trouble is that [people aren't sure what "Should Be Improved"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290977/1079354) means yet.  They think that, if the OP comes back, then that what they're looking at can be definitely improved.  The problem is that the OP doesn't always come back, and the community has to pick up where they left off.

I'm not sold that raising the reputation ceiling will fix anything.  If anything, it needs to be clear what "Should Be Improved" conveys; more specifically, it should be stated that a question that we think should be improved means that it can be improved by someone **other than** the OP.

Comment: I agree with your points about what the meaning of the phrase "Should Be Improved" is, but with millions of users on Stack Overflow, and a review count for this queue in the tens, there is a lot of room to tighten the group that uses it. Furthermore, are we looking at the same data? There is a steep decline (50% drop) in audit failure after reviewer reputation breaks the 2000 barrier. Which is to say **reputation is a strong indicator of review audit success**.

Comment: My issue (particulary with the review in question) was honestly because of my lack of undestanding what "Should Be Improved" really means and I'm a bit too nice when it comes to reviewing. I should be more strict and be more careful when using "Should Be Improved". I assumed that when choosing "Should Be Improved" the OP would come back and edit the question.

Comment: @JohnOdom: Yeah, that's the fatal assumption.  Don't feel bad; a lot of people have assumed the same thing (myself included for a time!), but so long as we improve it should be okay.  I really do want to see the language/scope of it greatly improved though.

Comment: @TravisJ: The statistics are not broken down quite so cleanly as all that, since that summary lumps *all queue audits together*, and therefore mixes in the 500-rep First Post reviewers with the 500-rep Triage reviewers in audit results, not to mention mingling the 2k Suggested Edit reviewers with the 2k Triage reviewers. If, then, the inclusion of suggested edit audits (lower failure rate than FP/LA) lowered the average failure rate at 2k, how would you distinguish that from triage reviewers getting better at 2k? Your conclusion is almost certainly statistically unsound.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Users can review triage at 500 reputation, so I am not sure why you would group them in with 2k?

Comment: @TravisJ: Users can also review Triage at 2k, at 3k, at 4k, and so on. That's my point: we have two overlapping sets of stats that are not fully broken down, and trying to do that breakdown after the fact from the summarized data is unreliable in the extreme. What you want to assert is that Triage reviewers get better at 3k. That data is not present as such.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Yes, they can and you can see the rate of review get better over time as the audit failure rate drops. And that is my point. That as reputation increases in the first couple thousand, the review failure rate drops to single digits. At present, aside from the data linked by Makoto from Shog, you can see real evidence of this happening straight from the link in my post here or by looking yourself at the triage queue review history.

Comment: @TravisJ: I don't have access to review queue history. Again, though, you're taking an aggregated statistic and trying to reverse the summarizing process. That does not work well. To give a clearer example, can you demonstrate how much of the reviewer accuracy increase is due to suggested edit reviewers getting better from 2k to 3k, how much is due to FP or LA reviewers getting better from 1k to 2k to 3k, and how much is due to triage reviewers getting better? No, you cannot. You can perhaps guess that they're roughly similar, but guesses are not data. The data is not present.

Comment: @TravisJ:  Notwithstanding that, once again, the data is mixed (other queues may be pulling those numbers up or down), you're glossing over the fact that failures spike at around 13,000.  You're also not taking into account the number of reviews done at each level - it does notably drop off after 3000 but that wonderful outlier 20K I suspect is an amalgam of everyone 20K and over.

Comment: @Makoto - I am glossing over it, or  you are completely reading the information incorrectly? There is a 6.8% audit failure rate at 13,000 reputation and that in no way represents a "spike".

Comment: Do not misinterpret number of reviews for reviewer reputation.

Comment: Look *around* 13,000.  12K and 14K have failure rates of 8%, so the statement that failure rates drop past 3K is inconclusive at best.

Comment: That is still significantly lower than the double digit numbers of lower reputation audit results.

Comment: But again - these are numbers for all review queues, not just triage.  Whose to say that high rep members are reviewing a lot in Triage?  Whose to say that this is reflective of just Triage?  I truly believe that you do not have enough evidence to conclude that there is a correlation between reputation and accuracy of reviews.  Until you can get more concrete numbers specifically about Triage, **your results are inconclusive.**  You just don't have enough evidence to prove your case here.  You have supposition, but that isn't evidence.

Comment: @Makoto - If these do not apply to triage, then why cite them as your primary source? Also note that for all users 10k to 20k the average failure of audits is 6.7%. You are the one who makes a point that this primary source shows no relation. However, *your evidence* states otherwise. Your conclusion based on this evidence is either flawed or misconstrued.

Comment: The reason I say this is three-fold.  1)  The reputation of a given user does not necessarily imply that their audit failure rate goes down.  2)  The reputation of a user has a direct impact on how many reviews across review types (and subsequently how many audits) they endure.  Note:  it's trending *down*.  High rep users review less.  3)  We've already established that getting "Should Be Improved" is fuzzy at best and should be worked on (which I believe it is), so the inference from the podcast is that the accuracy of users properly labeling things as "Should Be Improved" is spotty at best.

Answer (score 16):

I thought the whole idea of Triage was to reduce pressure on the CVQ by letting people with less rep help address the flaming obvious problems.

If you made the requirement the same, then what purpose would the Triage queue be serving?

Answer (score 4):

Given that Triage audits, [from the same answer you originally linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293789/), have less than half the failure rate of FP and LA audits, and given that those queues are unlocked at the same rep, and given that no distinction is made between queues within the given rep buckets, your analysis would seem far better suited to requesting that FP and LA thresholds be raised to 3k. Or better yet, 10k: just look at that juicy 3.87% failure rate! (Anyone with 19k should obviously not be permitted to review at all.)

Since that is *not* what you're requesting, perhaps your analysis needs to be reworked.

Comment: This issue is not addressing audits, it is addressing the need to limit users who are not fully aware of the way closures in general work because they have not been exposed to them. It makes sense to limit the privilege to review triage to a more relative place than where it currently sits.

Comment: @TravisJ: This answer was posted before the edit, so it no longer addresses what remains. Perhaps I should delete this, since it's apparently done its job.

Answer (score 2):

I've just started reviewing some questions, and I have often wished I'd get only questions which have tags to which I'm subscribed. That way, the material I get would be mostly of my interest and knowledge zone.

Though I can make a well-intentioned guess at other themes, sometimes I just feel uncomfortable doing so (and sometimes prefer 'skip').

I understand that this could probably leave a lot of questions out of the game, though if the questions was correctly tagged, then the majority should pass...

I'd be interested why this possibility isn't practical.

Comment: It is practical, but [that's a separate feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280773/review-triage-questions-accordingly-to-my-favorite-tags).

Answer (score -3):

Above question has the snip of triage review of my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295049/criteria-for-flagging-an-off-topic-question) posted at meta yesterday. I brought to notice that this question was not properly reviewed. I myself belong to 500-600 reputation group. My opinion is till you reach 500+ you get a fair idea about the site, what people need to do is stop reviewing just for the sake of badges and start reading the question before reviewing.

There are already test questions in the reviews to check if you are doing proper review. If you dont pass, I think there is ban on review for few days or so.