# Which restrictions exist for question titles?

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

I tried to edit a question title and wanted to insert the word "Problem", but could not submit the edit because this word is apparently not allowed in question titles (see example below; note: This is just an example using one of my own questions to reproduce the error message.).

[image: 'Problem' not allowed in question title]
(The link leads to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) on meta SE where good question titles are discussed.)

**What other restrictions apply to question titles?**

So far, after looking through some questions here on meta SO and the asking-related part of the Help Center, I could only find these four:

1. The ban on the word "Problem" as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268546/ban-on-the-word-problem-for-titles-makes-it-difficult-to-edit-existing-posts), and [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so).
2. A restriction for identical titles as discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists).
3. A maximum length of 150 characters.
4. A minimum length of 15 characters.

(Note: I don't want to start another discussion on whether a filter is good or bad, it has been led already and in a very emotional way, I'm just asking about other restrictions here.)

Comment: It might be that the exact rules for the filter are kept secret probably to make it a little harder for users to work-around them.

Comment: @rene That would make sense, indeed. On the other hand, having a comprehensive list of filtered expressions would not really do any harm because it is already easy to avoid the filtering, as shown in some of the links (replacing characters, using "issue" instead, etc.). Furthermore, I'm not only interested in the filter, but also any other constraints that might apply to question titles because I think it would be interesting to have them all collected in one place or find that collection if it already exists.

Comment: [An effort at such a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110885/which-words-in-titles-are-blacklisted-on-stack-exchange) can be found on the Overmeta.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nice, thanks! I guess I didn't find it because I was specifically looking for Stackoverflow, not Stack Exchange. That answers the filter part of my question.

Comment: There is such a list - it's just not public knowledge as per @rene's comment

Comment: Why would you need to put `Problem:` in front of your question? The act of posting a question means you have a problem.

Comment: @JonClements Is there a reason for it not being public other than that it might help people to circumvent restrictions? Just wondering, I would have expected a list like that in the Community Wiki or an FAQ.

Comment: @FranzWurst: Whom would it help?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't need to put it there. As I mentioned in the brackets, it's just an example to get a screenshot of the error window. However, the question I wanted to edit used one of the tricks to get around the ban and I thought it was some odd typo, so I tried to remove it which wasn't possible, hence my question about other kinds of restrictions. For some question titles it can be appropriate to use it, e.g. when people are talking about mathematical problems (like the Travelling Salesman Problem), but that's not the question here.

Comment: @Deduplicator People like me who love knowing how things work internally. :)

Comment: @Deduplicator Not saying it's important, I'm just curious about random stuff like that and wanted to know whether I missed something obvious everybody else in the Community knows about.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Maybe he wants to refer to a math problem? Or some day there will be a library/framework out there with "problem" in the name?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yup, that's the first "here" under point 1. that I'm linking to. ^^

Comment: @TylerH Such a library would be hilarious... But again, I don't really care about this specific example, just wanna know what else there is to question title restrictions.

Comment: I really doubt you're going to get an answer just because you're curious. Curiosity is known to be problematic for cats, and the internet runs on cats ;)

Comment: +1 Because someone had to bring up cats at some point :) And I'm gonna write up an answer myself later if nothing comes in anymore, just to gather what has been found so far.

Comment: Also, we've arranged it so that if you put "wanna" or "gonna" in your title, your keyboard will burst into flames. If you just put txtspk into a comment, your keyboard will get just a bit warmer.