# Should we remind OP about homework type questions automatically when the question contains keyword 'homework'?

Tags: feature-request

When [search with keyword 'homework'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Homework%20is%3Aquestion), it is not hard to see some questions are closed or having negative score, eg:

[Overridden function isn't called when using with statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177192)

[removing words that include anything that isn't letters regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996845)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062959

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980045

My question is, can we have a box to remind OP automatically when the question has word 'homework'?

Comment: Remind them of what? Questions that arise from homework aren't bad, bad questions are bad.

Comment: Here, here. And 95% of homework questions don't mention the "keyword".

Comment: Should you be reminded also here in meta? This question apears when you [search with keyword 'homework'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=homework)

Comment: @davidism - I'm guessing the OP wants to remind the user of this bit from the Help Center: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At one time, I was in favor of little automated functions like this.

Automation which solves an entire class of problems, like the Question Quality filter that StackExchange uses to block great swaths of badly-written, off-topic, ill-advised questions before the community ever sees them, are incredibly useful, saving the community many hours of unnecessary time and effort.

Small, incremental [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem) in site behavior like [restrictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314712/should-the-word-problem-always-be-blocked-from-titles) in [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298325/which-restrictions-exist-for-question-titles) [titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles)  [Not so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem) [much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so).

It is train wrecks like these (bad ideas, [jealously guarded by StackExchange corporate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter)) that cause me to remain deeply skeptical of this brand of seemingly innocent little changes that, while generally agreeable to the community and relatively easy to implement, invariably cause perverse incentives and unanticipated side effects.

I would avoid them.  They're not worth the trouble.

**Further Reading**
[The Scunthorpe Pr0blem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Comment: Now automatically putting all questions with "homework" into the LQP queue on the other hand...

Comment: @Servy: Just another ["question ghetto"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related).

Comment: I fail to see how using this keyword as a heuristic of the quality of a post to feed a review queue would cause a ghetto.  We wouldn't migrate all these questions elsewhere.  We'd close those that are bad, because the keyword *is* a decent heuristic of quality, and the good questions that happen to use the work get kicked out and answered.

Comment: @Servy  People would just stop using the word "homework" in their posts, and you'd be right back where you started.  You haven't thought it out.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd imagine most wouldn't even know that their question is going into the LQP filter because of the word. Or even that the LQP queue *exists*.

Answer (score 1):

The OP hasn't been specific about what the reminder should be. This answer assumes they mean a pop-up stating this from the Help Center:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

I don't think it would cause a problem and it's very likely the people writing homework questions that don't satisfy these requirements never saw this because they didn't go through the Help Center.

The question is, would it help enough to be worth doing. There's a similar thing where someone including a link to a fiddle gets a message telling them their question has to contain the code that duplicates the issue. I don't know if things were worse before this was added but I still see this:

> "[link to jsFiddle whose code changes as the OP tries various answers
>   and/or disappears as soon as they get something that works]"
>
> `add code here`

And more often this:

> "[link to jsFiddle...]"
>
> `A very small amount of actual code but nowhere near enough to duplicate the issue`

Now, some of them will fix it when you point out it's required, some will only do so after the question's been closed, and the rest will flat out refuse to do so and will argue with you if you tell them it's a requirement.

If the code notification has reduced the number of posts doing this, then I think this is worth trying, but I'd add this bit to the text...

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it. **Questions that fail to do so will be closed.**

...because some users will fix things if you make it clear that there are consequences if you don't (not just that it's required).

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion of course, but I personally believe we should give people who have "homework" or school assignments some encouragement to actively come on Stack Overflow and ask the professional / enthusiast community for our guidance on them.

They are, after all, potentially the next generation of programmers / developers!

For me, if I'm struggling with a particular issue for a good while and really can't figure it out, I do a Google / SO search and 99% of the time find something that either answers my problem or at least helps me along the way.

Getting students involved from as early as possible will encourage them to not just ask questions but hopefully to also answer them as their skills progress...

Whilst I agree that on the whole, homework-theme questions can be "lower quality" shall we say, simply filtering them out completely may put the up-and-comers off, which isn't good for anyone.

Comment: Unfortunately, too many students abuse SO contributors  by copy/pasting their assignments here first before making ANY effort themselves.  If a student is really that stuck, they should try to research their problem on their own first, then try their teacher/prof/TA and, only when they have theor code that perisitently fails to work after attempts at debugging, try posting here.  So many students do NOT do this, and so now I look at all posts of 'homework level' as spam from conmen and shysters, trying to get work done for free.

Comment: I don't wanna sound like the grumpy old _"Pah, I learned programming when there was no WWW, so them youths should also"_, but ... in fact, I do. We should _not_ encourage students to let their first course of action be to run to an internet site, and especially not teach them to get "guidance" from this site if it were a personal help forum. Why should we cut people who can't / don't want to debug some slack? Why wouldn't they have to post an on-topic, answerable question with an [mcve]?

Comment: @CodeCaster, definitely see your point - I too learned off my own back way before the days of SO, and certainly feel like I'm  a better programmer than I would've been had I had SO at my disposal. I just feel that it should be taken on a case by case basis (which it is), as I've seen some students post questions which are quite insightful and aren't just "please do this for me, I can't be bothered". When a question such as "Why do we do things like this and not like that" is better than "here's my code, fix it for me..."

Comment: @MartinJames, I certainly agree with you on this... One of my pet hates is when they literally copy and paste whatever their assignment is and expect the community to do it for them. Perhaps I need to rethink my overall view!!