# What to do when someone copies and pastes a 2 year old question as their own?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Some how it does not seem correct for someone to go find [old, unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017778/executing-vbs-via-batch-script-in-jenkins) and simply copy and paste them as [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619810/executing-vbs-via-batch-script-within-true-jenkins). I can't flag the question since the original is not answered, so what do we do about them. I mean, if doing this *IS* allowable, I know what I'm doing this afternoon. (just kidding ;-) )

Comment: Why can't you flag the new one? For moderator attention?

Comment: Doesn't work, you have to upvote the (correct) answer before you can close as dup.  Idiotic rule, it is the workaround.  Done.

Comment: Since it had to be asked twice, and still has no answer, it must be unclear, so down and close both of them as such.

Comment: Seeing as the new question is gone, I'm guessing that the problem has been resolved.

Comment: @LawfulEvil 9 downvotes, 5 duplicate closevotes, 3 deletevotes. You will be able to view deleted posts when you reach 10K ([moderator-tools privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)).

Comment: @Oriol, I guess at my level, its filtered out.  When I click the link, I get the "Page Not Found. This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. " page.

Comment: Meta-meta: Does a parenthetical ending in an emoticon need a second chin? Discuss...

Comment: @MrBoJangles: https://xkcd.com/541/

Comment: @MrBoJangles That's never been a problem for me (see? :} (or :]))! Oh shoot..

Comment: @Bergi you found the real advantage of emoji as distinct glyphs rather than digraphs.

Comment: If some time is passed and the old question still has no answer, why not to ask it again? you may keep link to original question and when one of them will get an answer it will be possible to mark another as a dup

Comment: _"Otherwise please mind your own business and dont hunt on reputations." – J.Doe._ Yea, that explains enough.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Copying and pasting another question - old or not, answered or not - to pass off as your own is blatant plagiarism.

Use a custom mod flag and explain the situation.

Comment: How do you know it's not the same person who didn't remember the old account login?

Comment: We don't. But it doesn't matter.

Comment: It matters in whether it is or isn't "blatant plagiarism".

Comment: @JDługosz: In any case, it's a bad practice to copy/paste, so there is no reason to keep the second. The mods may be able to check things better.

Comment: The way you people find new things to fight against here on stackoverflow is unbelievable... I mean, I can't believe someone considers reposting old questions a problem, let alone "blatant plagiarism".

Comment: @Dogcat: If you want an answer to an old question that wasn't well-answered, put a bounty on it.  (There's no "good" way to just bump it to the front page, though.  Maybe there should be for good questions that didn't attract answers.)  If you have a slightly different situation, ask your own question with a link to the very similar one.  Duplicate questions are already a bad thing for site quality (because it's harder to search if relevant answers are scattered over multiple questions).  It should be obvious that a word-for-word exact duplicate is a bad thing that makes the site worse.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I agree, it sounds great in theory but it doesn't really work. Imagine you're completely new to this site, you find a question that perfectly describes your situation but alas it has no answers. The only thing you can actually do is just post it again since you can't place a bounty for two reasons: a - you don't have enough reputation; b - you have no idea what bounties are.

Comment: @Dogcat Hey there! So if I understand correctly, one new here (or having a new account here) should be able to repost old content almost only to bump it?

Comment: @Dogcat: Yes, it's a problem.  I agree there should be a better way to bump a question for new attention.  However, even if you limit it to one bump ever per question per account, people will create dummy accounts to abuse it.  I have a hard time thinking of a way to allow legit uses without opening the floodgates to abuse by sock-puppets.  J.Doe's posting a non-answer, and then a copy, and some people taking pity on him and editing the original question to get it new attention clearly indicate that there's a need.  **Reposting it without links to the original is the worst way to allow it**

Comment: @Dogcat: I think I'd be ok with someone posting a new question that summarized **and linked to** an old question that looked ok but never got a good answer, since as you say there's no good way for a new user to proceed after searching and finding their question but no answer.  Then I could answer the original and mark the new one as a duplicate.  Or, if the new one was better-phrased and the old question was confusing, answer the new one and mark the old one as a duplicate.  It's **essential to link the question you're re-posting**.  I should post this as an answer to this meta Q I guess.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, adding a few more limitations can probably make it abuse-proof. Like "one bump ever per question per account" + "question can only be bumped once a month" + "new accounts can only bump once a week". It can be a separate feature available only to those who don't have enough reputation to use they bounty system. Though one can go crazy, get tons of new accounts and start bumping everything they see. But! (see my next comment)

Comment: @Peter Cordes If you move questions bumped this way in a separate tab (so they don't interfere with real new questions) it won't be an issue. And it also makes sense to do so because these "bumped questions" are of little use to the "reputation worshipers" who realize the poster won't probably bother to log in to rate/mark their answer.

Comment: @Dogcat: I just expanded those comments into an answer.  Interesting idea about the one bump per month for any given question.  IDK about the separate tab idea, though.  Catering to rep whores isn't normal SO practice.

Comment: Let's ___not___ implement a feature that somehow enables users to "bump" posts. Depending on the limitations set on it, it would be a large source of noise, or practically unusable. Besides, the users it'd be added for aren't exactly known for knowing how the site works. New users mostly just want answers. They don't care about old posts, they care about results.

Comment: @Cerbrus if such a feature would exist, it should not be anything like a BUMP. Rather, a link-pool to related posts that they want to bring up or relate. Promoting people to think about related posts should increase overall post quality, or at worst make it easier to tell up-front how "unique" the poster thinks their question is.

Comment: Users are already shown a list of questions that might be related. The problem is that that list is ignored. There's nothing one can add to prevent users from ignoring it.

Answer (score 7):

There is a legitimate problem here: as a new user, what do you do if your searching finds a question with your exact problem, but no good answer?

Your options are:

- put a bounty on the existing question:  impossible for new users.
- upvote / comment on the existing question: again impossible for new users, and unlikely to make much difference.  In theory, a comment like "@asker: did you ever solve this?  I'm having essentially the same problem with xyz..." might help, if the original poster is still active on SO.
- edit the original question to improve it, also bumping it for new attention.  New users can leave suggested edits, but this only helps if the original question wasn't well-asked.  An edit that just modifies whitespace to bump it would be rejected.  However, you can often **edit the tags** to add a relevant one (and drop a less-relevant one if needed).  In combination with leaving a comment, this is one of the more subtle and least-annoying ways to get new-attention to a question.
- post an "answer" which says "me too, I like to abuse this site and annoy people", bumping the question to the front page.
- bump the question for new attention using some feature which doesn't currently exist.  I don't think it's possible to implement such a feature that allows legit use without being easy to abuse.  Even with a limit of one bump ever per question per account, people will create sock-puppets to abuse it.  (@Dogcat suggests [a limitation of one bump per week or month for each question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321128/what-to-do-when-someone-copies-and-pastes-a-2-year-old-question-as-their-own/321135?noredirect=1#comment334089_321135), which might do the trick.

  Still, this potential feature mainly benefits people that aren't contributing to SO (yet).  After they have even a bit of rep, they have other options.
- **post a new question**

---

There are many wrong ways to post a new question.  Copy&Paste is one of the worst, because apart from all the other problems, it raises the issue of plagiarism and getting rep from question-upvotes from someone else's carefully-worded question.

However, I think there are ways to do it that aren't too bad.

**I think the best approach for a new user is**:

Check your search results for other similar questions, because the question you found may have duplicates that it doesn't link to.  (We try to avoid this, but duplicates still slip through the cracks.  Duplicate questions are terrible for SO's quality as a collection of good answers to good questions.)

If the old question is exactly what you wanted to ask, write a new question that summarizes it **and links to it**.  Also include links to all other potential duplicates you found while searching, so people that see this new question can come and link the duplicates together.

If your question is slightly different, write it up as a stand-alone question, but still include a link to the similar question.

Be sure to include any relevant details that are specific to your problem, because maybe your situation has an easy or different answer than the original, if something is different that you didn't realize was a big deal.

I think I'd be ok with someone posting a new question that re-asked and linked to an old question.  Even if it was just a summary + link.  Summary + link is actually better in some ways than re-stating the same stuff as the duplicate, because then I only have to read it once, not twice and check that they're the same.

I could answer the original and mark the new one as a duplicate.  Or, if the new one was better-phrased and the old question was confusing or cluttered or littered with comments, answer the new one and mark the old one as a duplicate.  If there's a half-decent answer on the other question, I could improve and upvote it, then mark the new Q as a duplicate.

It's not ideal to have a new question that mostly just links to an old question, but it does show that the asker searched before asking.  **As long as the new question is clear and sensible**, I'd be sympathetic since it's the least-bad option.  This is by no means a free pass to break other rules for question quality.

It's **essential to link the question you're re-asking**, whether the old question is good (well-phrased and clear) or bad (rambing, un-clear, really specific with lots of irrelevant details, or cluttered with comments on an early version, even if it's since been edited to suck less).

Comment: How do you suggest new users are to be made aware of this rather complex procedure? The idea is great, but I don't see this as something that will ever actually happen.

Comment: @Cerbrus: No idea.  Maybe add a link to this explanation in the same place it tells you that "answers are not for me-too posts and stuff like that"?  Maybe condense this down into something that can go in the "how to ask" guide?  New users are expected to have read that to avoid wasting other people's time.

Comment: Expected to have, yes. But experience teaches us they rarely do.

Comment: @Cerbrus: SO doesn't do enough to guide users towards finding duplicates, IMO.  There should be a checklist for low-rep users where they check off "yes, I searched", "yes, I included the actual error messages I'm getting in my question", etc. etc. maybe with some heuristics to choose which checkboxes to require.  Some kind of machine-learning expert system that can read questions as search terms, and find answers before people every post their bad questions would be awesome.

Comment: I don't disagree, but adding multiple checks before someone can post an question isn't very good UX. Especially when that user _did_ do his research, and just wants to post an question. Besides, everyone always clicks "agree" any way.

Comment: I think an added option to link to related threads when creating a thread would get people to question themselves whether they have searched before asking. It shouldn't be necessary but it would remind people that the question may have been asked before.

Comment: @Dmitry Here's a rough idea which is poorly worded, http://i.imgur.com/R6lcIdq.png . Something like "Linked questions" would be better worded I think.

Comment: What makes you think new users will add references like that? Besides, questions linked in the question are already shown in the sidebar.

Comment: @Cerbrus they don't have to, it's mostly to deal with people intentionally trying to revive a discussion, or want to make an initial impression that they searched. The way I see it at least. Ideally the feature should not stand out too much, nor be expected to be filled out.

Comment: @Cerbrus it may also remedy the rare cases when newcomers may doubt if they are allowed to include links or not(or whether their question quality improves from adding them, or not). I am not sure how often that is, but I am certain it happens.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Some new users just don't realize how the site worked and was meant to be used.  Or they're not very good at thinking about what people will need to know to be able to help them.  More guidance towards searching / linking instead of just posting will help some new users.  My checkbox idea is one I've [already suggested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316312/prompt-users-to-post-errors-instead-of-i-get-an-error/316374#316374) on an unrelated question about how to prompt users to post questions that don't suck.

Comment: The majority just doesn't bother reading the introduction, they just want to ask a question. Those are the problematic users. Adding more text to the intro doesn't help for those users.

Comment: @Cerbrus This kind of feature would focus more on making how unique a person thinks their question is. There will always be people who, for whatever reason hurry to post their question without any care for guidelines. There are many ways to try to mitigate many of them, but not all. In particular, small hints to make these people aware that it's very unlikely that such posts would be answered, and very likely that they will regret posting them. Small hints though, it's  too easy to discourage people from asking at all.

Comment: How does this add to the _already shown_ list of relevant questions? A better option would be to fix the logic behind that list to show better (more relevant) results.

Comment: @Cerbrus the first thing that pops to mind is that it reminds people that posting links in their posts where they have looked is encouraged, which aids the shy minority of new posters. I don't see much overlap; the relevant questions box helps remind people that others have asked similar questions, while linkpool would remind people that links are encouraged, and provide a way to for people to see that this post is intending to continue a discussion(s),  rather than create a new one. It can also allow people looking up answers to see posts that linked this one post.

Comment: Is _"Users being too shy to post links"_ really a problem? Also, is it relevant to this question?

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right, it's not a problem, but it is something that would be improved with such a feature. It adds to the already shown list of relevant questions by allowing people reading the post to quickly see which, if any, relevant questions the user has already considered. This avoids wasted effort by people who are writing answers which are already provided in the links, and respects the thread which is similar but lacks the answer the poster seeks. Surely this merits as relevant to the question.

Comment: This question is about how to handle plagiarism. If you have a suggestion on how to improve a different scenario, post a suggestion in a new meta question.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right. Perhaps I lost track of the purpose of the discussion. You're good at what you do.

Answer (score 3):

Not all posts that appear really similar are downright plagiarism. Most are, but many discussions genuinely may be worthwhile to continue.

Granted, I wish we had an ability to tag new posts as a continuation of an earlier locked discussion. This way new posts are promoted, while their context is preserved.

Continuing discussion has a benefit of notifying people who were present at the time, whereas new posts don't respect the fact that they have been asked before, and people will be tempted to provide answers which are already given in the older posts, but are no longer sufficient, or were never sufficient.

I agree, posting old question as your own(with exception to small questions with unfortunately hard-to-find similar posts) is not okay. All old questions should be respected before new ones are posted to ensure those involved are dealing with something interesting, and not wasting their time.

**NOTE**: On StackOverflow, necroposting isn't an issue. I talked about it to bring up the intent of continuing an old discussion, and tried to go over how it is perceived in general over different forum-like communities. A point I forgot to mention is that adding a feature to promote links would make intentional plagiarism more obvious, and remind people that showing that you looked for answers will generally encourage others to take their question more seriously.

Comment: Necroposting ___isn't___ a problem. It isn't even what this meta question is about. Blatantly copy-pasting a old question ___is___.

Comment: In response to your edit: _Necroposting **ISN'T** an issue_. Period. _"isn't as much..."_ implies that it _is_ an issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am shy at making strong statements as I wasn't sure if there was some way for necroposting to be a problem that I am not aware of. But if you assert, I'll edit it out. I was simply unaware if it was an issue, and saying that it isn't and being caught wrong felt more uncomfortable. Thinking that there is no issue does not necessarily warrant saying that there is no issue, so I try to be careful.

Comment: Look at it this way: If you come across a 4-year old (good) question that isn't answered but can be answered now, go for it! A answer adds value (as in content) to SO.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the question asked here:

> What to do when someone copies and pastes a 2 year old question as their own?

Flag it, so a mod can have a look at it. Make sure you link to the original post in the flag message.
Plagiarism is a serious offence that's not taken kindly to.

Don't mark it as duplicate, since the only desirable outcome of plagiarized content is for it to be deleted.

*That's all there is to it.*

---

The discussion on a couple of answers here, about pointing new users in the right direction, is pointless.

The new users that plagiarize like this **don't care** what we throw at them. They just want results. Extra suggestions, rules, help, links or whatever isn't going to change that.

New users that *do* read the help section usually have the common sense not to plagiarize.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of posters here making suggestions about designing a new feature to allow users to bump a question that never got any good answers, and other (more experienced) posters noting how prone to abuse this would be.

But all that is entirely beside the point, because there ***already is*** such a feature. [Community ♦ automatically chooses questions with 0-scored answers to bump from time to time](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579). The original question was eligible for this. And trying to circumvent the rate-limited features that are designed to manage this appropriately is *abuse of the site*, period. That's worth a mod flag.