# Are users allowed to call you 'sketchy' just because you can't express yourself well?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651962/extending-a-function-using-override-for-inherited-class) and a user decided to call me sketchy as * simply because I had difficulty in expressing myself. I thought I was doing a good job and tried making it clear (wrote notes in my notebook to make sure others understand my question), but I didn't do a good job.

Why did they take the assumption I am trying to profit off someone else when I am asking a question. How is that 'profitable'? My English isn't the best but just because I'm hard to understand, I'm sketchy? Making profit's off people's hardwork? Running a scam?

Comment: No mods involved. Just a normal user. Mods have diamonds next to their names (so do SO employees).

Comment: Downvotes on meta means that people disagree with you - you don't lose/gain any reputation on meta. And those are not [moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) - those can be recognized by the ♦ behind their names. If you have a problem with some comments, just flag them and a real moderator will deal with them.

Comment: If you think the comment is unconstructive or even rude just flag it.  Then a real mod will step in and take any necessary steps to remove bad comments.

Comment: but he has the sheriff badge. I just read here people who have that were mods.

Comment: @J.Doe That just means at one time he was a mod.  If he does not have a diamond next to his name he is not a mod.

Comment: oh alright thank you. i felt so scared seeing so many downvotes. okay please stop with downvotes i get it no one agrees with me. thank you

Comment: but do i seem sketchy? from my question?

Comment: Asking for less downvotes... ESPECIALLY on meta, will just result in MORE downvotes.

Comment: okay thanks for letting me know. i am new here

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, yes you do.

Comment: @servy, how can i improve this? what was wrong with my question

Comment: As for the downvotes to this meta question, your title is (was) incredibly misleading and even incorrect.  That's why I downvoted this meta question.

Comment: @CubeJockey, I edit it but how will it self destruct

Comment: Haha alright @cubeJockey :)

Comment: Ahh, I see you already met Will. That [Won't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228/wont) be the last time ...

Comment: This doesn't deserve -5; this really isn't your fault. -1, maybe, but I don't think it deserves negative score.

Answer (score 14):

If,

- Two different users with the exact same name (J. Doe) with similar gravatars
- both posting a question close enough together so that someone browsing the list of questions would see both of them
- but still with enough time between so a single person could have easily posted both
- where the first person was caught copying and reposting a question verbatim
- and the second person posts a poorly formatted, unclear, bizarrely tagged question
- but a check of the second person's post history shows very well written and formatted, clear and concise questions, almost like *someone else wrote them...*

a person, *who might or might not be me*, browsing new questions might see all this and mistake the two people for the same person.

A person, *who I think is me but i'm not sure*, may think that this J. Doe is unable to ask a good question, but still wants to gain rep and not get post banned.

A person, *who I'm now thinking could be me*, may believe J. Doe has hit upon an idea--find older, upvoted questions and repost them in the hopes that they too will gain upvotes.  An idea that more than one person has been caught having, mind you.

A person, *who people keep telling me is me but I still think there's a possibility they may be wrong...* a person might think this J. Doe is doing this to counteract the downvotes they get when they have to post their own questions.

A person, *who I think isn't me again*, may flag this J. Doe's question with details about what he or she believes is going on, and shares details about this sketchy behavior in a comment or two.

A person, *who definitely isn't me I'm convinced about it*, may have made a mistake.  And they might feel bad about it, and wish to extend you an apology.  It isn't the first time they've stuck their foot in it, nor will it be the last.

This person, *never seen him before in my life, I swear*, may even suggest you rewrite your latest question to change your pseudocode into actual compilable C#, so people can reopen and answer it.  This person certainly knows you're capable of doing this, because you've got some very clear and well formatted questions in the past.

But I dunno, we need to ask this person guy.

Comment: Gee, I've got no idea who this person is either, but sounds like they made an honest mistake, and are at least a big enough person to admit their mistake and even offer advice to the user they made upset. I hope we can figure out who it was, they deserve a "great job, you did a good" comment. Oh well, guess I'll just upvote your good response instead.

Comment: We really need to hunt down that person and make him God of Stack or something... shame it isn't you Will, our search would already be over ;) (in general though, nice job relating how you saw it. From that point of view, your actions make a lot more sense :)

Comment: Hmm, this is a pretty sketchy flogging.  But, please, don't stop screwing up.

Comment: Haha that person should be happy to find out I managed to solve the issue myself :). Also let that person know I am trying to improve my question-asking skill.

Answer (score 12):

I am sorry for the comments you received.  There was a [recent meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321128/what-to-do-when-someone-copies-and-pastes-a-2-year-old-question-as-their-own) about a user doing some really sketchy behavior.  The OP of that question has(at the time of this incident) the same username as yourself.  I believe that the user that commented confused you with that other OP.  I did leave a comment to that user pointing that out.

Comment: oh thank you for letting me know. i felt so bad for being called that. thank you :)

Comment: a lot of users over here probably pick the [same username](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe)

Comment: Yeah I'll probably change my username after this.