# Two questions with the same body - is this a weird kind of spam?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, plagiarism

Earlier today I encountered the question [Inner join inverse Php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38343898/2422776) by @sanjay. This is a relatively new user with low rep, and this is his fourth question. Although the formatting and possibly the phrasing could be improved, it seems to be a valid question, and it indeed sparked some back-and-forth conversation in its comments, with other users asking for clarifications and the OP providing them.

About five minutes later, I encountered the question [Allign image on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38343975/2422776) by @mluci. Although this user has been a member for about three months, this question seems to be his first activity on SO - no other questions, answers, votes or flags. Before the post was edited (by other users), it contained exactly the same text as the previous one, with just two differences:

1. A different title, that doesn't seem to have any relation to the question's body.
2. A link with no context, presumably back to a site the user is trying to promote (mluci.com - I did not click through).

Is this a weird new kind of spam here on SO? What would be the right way to deal with such posts? Editing them (as a few users already did)? Flagging as spam? Raising a custom flag? Something else?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was the user who edited the signature out.

I came across the question by mluci in the [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12988927), and saw the signature. Usually in these cases (it happens rather frequently that people put signatures in questions/answers) I edit the signature out and leave a comment, which is what I did in this case, because the question looked otherwise legit.

Now that you found out that it's a direct copy of the other question, the appropiate course of action is to raise a moderator flag and explain. If it's indeed considered a spammer, the moderators will take care of it sooner rather then later.

**UPDATE:** In response to the custom flags raised, the second question by mluci has been deleted and the user has been destroyed.

Comment: "... and the user has been destroyed." that sounds like from sci-fi, +1

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Moderators can destroy very low rep (>200) accounts. This immediately deletes them, all their posts, invalidates their votes and deletes their comments. Its handy.

Comment: @Magisch Should that be `<200` **not** `>200`?

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is spam, but it is unfortunately not weird nor new. More and more spam (and other dubious activities) plagiarizes content in order to avoid detection.

- Sometimes, the link is very well hidden: [Our policy on posts with hidden link spam to the author's website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320786)
- Sometimes, it's just a troll: [deleted answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105581/6083675) and [deleted answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio/37105566#37105566) copied the text of the accepted answer, but added random pop singers to the top.
- Sometimes, it's just plain old plagiarism, possibly in an attempt to get rep fraudulently: [What to do when someone copies and pastes a 2 year old question as their own?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321128)

**Just flag for moderator attention and explain that it's plagiarism/spam.** Also, link to the original. The true nature of the beast isn't obvious unless you know it was plagiarized, so these things are unlikely to get other spam flags anyway.

---

In this case, it seems to be taken care of already.