# The same person seems to be asking the same question twice with two different accounts

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, duplicate-accounts

I've encountered something suspicious when doing triage review. I came across two questions with very similar titles, very similar code, both about the same programming language and asked by two users with very similar names.

I also looked at the editing history and the original questions were even more similar to each other.

Of course, this could be a coincidence, but I think that it is very likely that this is the same user who for some reason created two accounts and posted the same question twice.

Is this kind of behavior allowed? If not, what should I do about it?

Comment: Could have been two people in the same class getting other people to do the same homework assignment too. Either do as Servy says, or just flag one as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I could imagine that there's a user using SSO and a normal account and just accidentally posting the same question when they can't log in properly.

Comment: Did one of the original questions contain a link anywhere? If so, it may be just a robot reposting the question as a spamming technique (see, e.g., the discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327838/2422776)).

Comment: @Mureinik No, it didn't. The questions both contained something like "can you help me please?" and then some code that was very similar in both questions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You flag the post and inform the moderator that a user appears to be repeatedly posting the same question under different accounts.

Comment: Should I flag both posts or only one of them?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Why would you need to cast multiple flags for the same issue?  Obviously you'd want to link to the duplicate in the flag, rather than just saying that one exists.  If you start seeing new duplicates *after* your flag gets handled (because the user starts posting more duplicates of the question) then yeah, sure, flag again.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, only one of them.

Comment: I've done this (where the same user posted a duplicate question under the same account, one day apart). The flag was declined with the statement: "declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?" My take away on that was that I should either A) just vote to close as a duplicate, or B) flag it as a duplicate (without the ability to provide any explanation that it is the same user, or possibly related users).

Comment: @Makyen the huge difference is the user being the same. The system shouldn't even allow flagging an unanswered duplicate if the users are different. The reason why these questions need a custom mod flag is that two active accounts by possibly the same user are an abuse of the system, and need moderator intervention (if it turns out that the accounts belong to the same user, they should be merged with an optional suspension for the remaining account).

Comment: @AndrasDeak, The person using multiple accounts is a potential *additional* issue. [Having multiple accounts is acceptable, except when it enables you to do things which you *can not do* with one account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/271271). Thus, the same person posting duplicate questions is either a problem which should be flagged (regardless of it being the same account, or another account), or identical questions by the same user is not a problem that should be flagged. If it is not to be flagged for the same user, then it should not be flagged for multiple accounts.

Comment: @Makyen flagging is for issues that the community cannot address on its own. Since you can't vote to close questions without answers from different users, that qualifies IMO

Comment: @psubsee2003, That is a valid point which is potentially relevant to my declined flag. I quite agree that the correct thing to do for *duplicate* questions is to flag them as duplicates (or vote to close as a duplicate). Neither this question, nor this answer, mention anything about the answered/unanswered state of either question. More importantly, this question is about questions which are at least very, very similar (if not near identical). This question and answer state that the correct thing to do when one sees a *near identical* question (not just a duplicate) is to flag.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It is *not* against the rules to have multiple accounts.  You should not be flagging posts just because you suspect has multiple accounts, and these accounts wouldn't merit merging.  It's simply not possible to close unanswered questions as duplicates unless they are from the same user, so when the duplicate questions are from the same user, you can just vote to close, when they're not, you need a mod to do it (they don't have that restriction).  Of course if someone has multiple accounts and you suspect voting fraud, or other behavior they couldn't do with one account, then flag.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure about that. I mean, yeah, there are many valid cases for multiple accounts, usually testing and bots. But I don't think two "active" accounts (as I worded earlier), which ask questions, are a natural thing. I believe users usually do that to get out of question bans, hence abuse, hence my notion to flag. Are there typical and common reasons for multiple Q&A accounts that I didn't think of?

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's against the rules to use multiple accounts to do things that you couldn't do with a single account.  Getting around a question ban would of course qualify, and merit a flag.  Just asking questions normally from two different accounts is *not*, and wouldn't merit action.