# Should I flag comments that are encouraging OP to use ChatGPT to write their code?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, comment-flags, chatgpt

A *new contributor* just asked a very broad question, something like:

> Can you write a simple broadcast script in JavaScript or php just give me an example or if you brief explain please explain

The question was quickly closed as *needs details or clarity*. However, a moment later this comment was added:

> You should provide code example of what you tried. **Otherwise, just ask chat.openai.com/chat for this**.

---

Since ChatGPT generated content [is not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), are comments where someone suggests using ChatGPT to write their code allowed?

What is the policy regarding this?

Should I flag the comment?

Comment: Flag them as no longer needed; they aren't useful or helpful, and they don't contribute to the Q&A.

Comment: This comment should be flagged regardless of whether it recommends ChatGPT or not. It's simply not needed and never was needed.

Comment: @Dharman consider the comment be 'needed' is some sense, but they still recommend using ChatGPT, should it also be flagged?

Comment: [Comments can't contain that content - "What have you tried?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251309/1839439)

Comment: "Otherwise, just ask chat.openai.com/chat for this." - Is as helpful as replying with "Otherwise, just Google for this" is likely as friendly, so I would probably flag it as unfriendly and unkind

Comment: "chatGPT is banned" doesn't mean the mention of chatGPT is banned. It's not the tool that must not be named.

Comment: @Security Hound It is not as "ask google". Since ChatGPT is quite new, the OP  probably didn't think about it. Moreover, it is for the moment unclear what GPT is good for. So pointing that GPT is good for that particular question *is* an helpful hint. Analogy : "how can I avoid typos in my code ? -- install a linter"

Comment: @LaurentClaessens truth be told, linters HAVE helped me to fix quite some issues while writing (typescript) code. Avoidance however is not possible since they only work on what you already typed :)

Comment: @LaurentClaessens - Any comment that suggested OpenGPT instead of just submitting an answer would be considered unhelpful unnecessary and immediately flagged as “no long needed” which is identical to any comment that suggested I Google for my answer. OpenGPT is a unhelpful useless tool unlike a search engine.

Comment: @Dharman The comment is needed if the question is low quality because the asker has not shown the code that is not working.

Comment: @SecurityHood " OpenGPT is a unhelpful useless tool unlike a search engine." -- citation needed ;) I suppose that the OP does not know about chatGPT, or does not know that it is able to generate javascript. Giving a pointer to a tool that may help resolving the question is helpful.

Comment: by the way, just put the OP's question about broadcast in chatGPT will fix the question about its ability of giving something helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree with @LaurentClaessens on this one. IMO, you are forcing your subjective view on someone else. (In some time, maybe questions won't be excepted if they can be answered by AI.) There are so many comments out there that say something like "Just Google it", which are not flagged.

Comment: A link to Chat GPT is **NOT a ChatGPT-generated content**. You should revise your question to mention other policies that are applicable to comments. This one is clearly not applicable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Mentioning ChatGPT in comments isn't banned. Posting content generated by ChatGPT is!

Comments can be used to ask for more clarification and/or provide constructive criticism about the post. All other comments can be flagged as no longer needed and deleted.

The comment you used as an example was never needed. The first sentence is an impolite request for a code example. The second one is just a useless recommendation that doesn't help to answer the question in any way.

Just flag as no longer needed. It's the same as a comment redirecting the user to Reddit, Quora, etc.

Comment: I agree, thanks. Imagine the comment be useful, but it still ends with encouraging to use ChatGPT, is it still desired to flag those too?

Comment: It depends. You can ask mods to edit the comment. A mod may delete it anyway. If the comment contains a useful part then it can be reposted.

Comment: In other words, mentioning ChatGPT is not forbidden. It's forbidden to post content generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: Okay, Find it difficult to distinguish 'mentioning' from 'recommending'. But I will Flag them if needed.

Comment: @0stone0 a recommendation is a mention, a mention is not always a recommendation. However in the context of a Stack Overflow comment, it is a safe assumption it is intended as such.

Comment: I'm shocked that comments are not allowed to tell askers what they should do to improve their questions.

Comment: @user253751 They are allowed. The comment that was used as an example isn't telling the asker how to improve the question.

Comment: Generally, showing a failed attempt is an improvement of the question as it identifies specifically how the asker is stuck. Generating one with ChatGPT is not useful.

Comment: I don't agree. Often the failed attempt is a distraction.

Comment: Well, anyone posting such comments are likely posting ChatGPT-generated answers themselves. So a brief peek at their most answers wouldn't hurt.

Comment: How is "Show us your code" (essentially the same statement as "You should provide code example of what you tried") not suggesting to the user how to improve their question?  I agree that failed attempts at coding can be a distraction, but that's essentially what we get when we ask for an MCVE.  Is "Please supply an [MCVE]" the only allowable comment nowadays, or is even that forbidden?

Comment: [What have you tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251309/1839439) is something else; it's a statement that implies prior coding effort is required to ask a question (it isn't).  As a former mod, I understand the difference.

Comment: And for what it's worth, mods shouldn't make it their full time occupation to police comments.  If a comment is genuinely harmful to the site, then delete it with great vengeance and furious anger.  Otherwise, there are bigger fish to fry.

Comment: I mean.. it's the same question, just presented in a way that for some reason has convinced a consensus of users isn't just the same question behind a mask.

Comment: My point is that it's not a hill to die on.  There was a time when people were asking this question all the time, demanding effort from question askers before they could be answered.  That's not what this is.

Comment: Relevant: [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/191410)

Comment: "_The first sentence is outright banned_" - please provide a link. I have been on this site for 13 years and I've never seen that a request for a code example is banned.

Comment: @JDB: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried) is what they are talking about. 
 It's an actual ban, put in place by the Stack Overflow programmers. 
 I just tried it, and it is still in effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdlPg.png

Comment: @RobertHarvey A comment that just ask for their code is meaningless and comes down to the old "What have you tried". If there's something missing from the question, vote to close as "lacks MCVE" and in the comments explain what particular information is missing. A comment isn't required, but may be helpful to the author who may not know what exactly is missing from the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree.  There's enough uncertainty about site mechanics (I haven't seen a 10 rep question view in years) to know that the OP may not have any idea what happened, or what to do about it, if you simply Vote to Close.  That's the reason we have a comment system in the first place.  To echo the words of your fellow mod below, "assume good faith."

Comment: I am all for making a comment when voting to close. But the comment has to say something meaningful. You can't just add a comment that says "Please add MCVE" because that's what the close reason already says. It's pointless. But if you say "please show us the code from the function XYZ" then it's a different story.

Comment: Not for nothing, but SE provided the MCVE shortcut link for comments precisely so that folks could intelligently ask for one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I know that "_What have you tried?_" is banned. But I'd like Dharman to provide backup for the assertion that "_You should provide code example of what you tried._" is banned. I have requested **code examples** more times than I can count for questions that don't provide any. "_What have you tried_" is way too open-ended to be useful, but asking for source code or an example is perfectly acceptable (given that [it's in our own docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)!)

Comment: "What have you tried" is BANNED? We can all certainly agree that there's no sane reason for that, but can somebody explain what the pretext is? Anything at all? Or is ChatGPT in charge of moderation here now? Ever time I look in on this site, the more I'm glad I am I quit wasting my time contributing.

Comment: @15ee: That ban happened nearly ten years ago.  There was a significant period of time when newcomers to the site were constantly being asked "What have you tried?" under the mistaken assumption that questions must demonstrate effort. Hence the ban.  As to the automated enforcement, I have always been adamantly opposed to that, for reasons that really [should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316142/102937) be [obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: The **only** questions that need a code example of what you've tried are debugging questions, @JDB. This is spelled out in [the text of the close reason on the page you linked](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The requirement for a minimal, reproducible example applies *only* to "[q]uestions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?')". Thus, asking people who are asking a "how-to" question for a code example is silly, pointless, and wrong. It's also worth noting that, while on-topic, debugging questions are the least interesting & least useful additions to our knowledge base.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This kind of woke garbage is why I don't contribute to the site anymore. You don't want to build a platform that generates developers who actually understand the code they write. You're just going along with the "generate as much traffic to make money off users" crowd because they bury it under some BS about "helping people." Asking what you've tried isn't some kind of "effort tax;" it's about ensuring that the person is actually engaging their brain in the problem and have some understanding of what they're doing so that they can actually learn something from the answer.

Comment: @CodyGray On the contrary, a "how to" question **should** demonstrate an attempt to solve it. Even if it doesn't include a code sample, it should detail some solutions attempted and why they didn't work out. Doing so reveals a great deal about the asker's understanding of the problem and will often make it obvious what information they are missing. It will also reveal limitations that make common solutions inapplicable, which can then lead to common alternatives for those situations, and will make XY problems readily apparent. Code samples give us even more context to craft suitable answers.

Comment: We don't care about the asker's understanding of the problem, @jpmc26; that's just noise in a "how-to" question, and it causes the answers that it produces to be less helpful to future viewers, which is who we primarily aim to benefit. We're not a help desk. It's not our job to assess whether the asker has sufficiently engaged their brain. If you don't think the question shows sufficient research effort, downvote it. It's not a close reason. It's only a close reason if the question is actually underspecified or overly broad. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909

Comment: We do care about the asker's understanding to the extent that it helps us answer their question.  Questions asked by folks who don't have a fundamental understanding of the problem because they lack basic skills are not going to understand any answer we give them without a whole lot of hand-holding.

Comment: @jpmc26: Let me clarify my position.  The phrase "what have you tried" is lazy, and it says exactly what it means: "I think *you're* lazy."  "Please provide a [mcve]" is different; it asks for more information, it's backed by site policy, and it's informative because it links to the Help Center.

Comment: @CodyGray We're not here to blindly provide information without understanding the context of how it will be used. That leads to [idiotic advice like ignoring the importance of encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/1394393) that then gets thousands of upvotes from people who have no idea what they're reading.

Comment: @CodyGray - Even a how-to question requires some context, as was thoroughly discussed in this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210844/191410. Depending on the question, that might mean some starter code, but it really depends on the question. Quoting [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "_The best Stack Overflow questions generally have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers…_"

Comment: "Please provide a [mcve]" is no less lazy than "What have you tried". however, the former *at least* points the user to a page where they can read a little bit more on the subject.

Comment: Dharman, sorry to bring this up again, but you haven't answered my question about the "banned" comment. Can you please clarify? Happy to ask a separate Meta question if this is worthy of a longer discussion/answer. Your status as a mod lends authority to your post and I'd like to know whether or not comments asking for code examples are truly banned (and, whether they or not, what the policy is here).

Comment: @JDB This conversation has strayed off-topic. If you want to get a proper answer, please start a new topic. This comment section isn't the place to discuss this.

Comment: @JDB FWIW I removed that part of the answer. It resulted in unnecessary discussion under this post which was never my intention.

Answer (score 19):

I'm assuming good faith of the commenter who genuinely tries to help the OP. Here's how I would rephrase it (that is: manually, I don't need an A.I. for this):

> either provide your non-working code so we can suggest how to fix it
>
> or - as your question seems very fit for ChatGPT, that you may not know so I'm providing you with the link - ask that A.I. and it may actually help you.
>
> Since the question is pretty vague, you'll get a vague answer, but which may be informative, just don't rely on the accuracy of the code it should provide!

As long as the user doesn't post the ChatGPT reply as a self-answer (which violates our policy), that's fine. This technology *can* be helpful *for personal use*. Just not as answers to Stack Overflow questions.

The comment can be useful to the OP, and can be safely deleted (but as *no longer needed* only) after a few days.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP's next move will be to edit their question, insert the ChatGPT generated code, and ask for help making it work. Is that OK? If not, does it mean that the suggestion is bad?

Comment: @tgdavies see [Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422439/11107541). From the top answer: "_Asking a question about ChatGPT output is no different from asking questions about other code you found somewhere, be that documentation, a tutorial, or another Stack Overflow answer._"

Answer (score 2):

**..are comments where someone suggests using ChatGPT to write their code allowed?**

Pointing someone to a specific tutorial or API documentation page is great in a comment, but asking someone to Google their question is almost always discouraged (even if you offer to [write the search terms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added) yourself).

ChatGPT isn't significantly different from a search engine (except, perhaps, that it doesn't always cite its sources). While not strictly against the rules, I would strongly encourage users not to recommend ChatGPT unless the question is specifically about AI, etc, and ChatGPT would be relevant to the question.

Or put another way: if you could copy-paste the comment onto just about any other randomly selected question, then it's probably not a useful comment.

**What is the policy regarding this?**

The [current ChatGPT policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) is for copying content from ChatGPT and offering it as your own answer:

> the posting of answers created by ChatGPT is substantially harmful to the site and to users who are asking and looking for correct answers.

Mentioning ChatGPT in a comment does not, strictly speaking, run afoul of this specific policy. However, comments mentioning ChatGPT aren't therefore exempt from all of our other comment policies. I think the most relevant is the one linked above regard [LMGTFY](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added)

**Should I flag the comment?**

In this case, for the sake of efficiency, probably not.

Questions like this one are of such low quality that they are unlikely to have a very long life on SO. Nearly all other moderation efforts are moot if the author doesn't bother to write a question that will survive closure and eventual deletion (the only exception to my mind being unkind/abusive comments, where the comment author may need correction more than the question author).

Obviously you are thinking beyond this particular question, in which case the policy on [telling users to "Google it"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280426/should-comments-saying-google-it-be-flagged) is, I think, most relevant:

> Personally I'd flag such comments as not constructive.
>
> The comment is indeed not helpful, not to the OP and not to future visitors. Either show how googling it would have found the information, or not comment at all.

We no longer have the "Not Constructive" category, so "It's no longer needed" would be the nearest corollary (""*This comment is outdated, conversational or **not relevant to this post**.*"")

Comment: ChatGPT is a bit more than just a search engine.  It is a language model that can respond to questions with actual answers, and it has the capability to write code.  ChatGPT is more suitable for OPs that don't quite know how to ask proper questions (or who need a bit of hand-holding), something that Stack Overflow is generally not willing to accommodate.

Comment: LMGTFY is a different problem.  It's in the same league as "What have you tried?"  Civility is the key; if you're genuinely trying to be helpful and direct someone to a resource that can better assist them, I don't see how you can be faulted for that.

Comment: For the folks who really do need to Google their question first, my approach is: *"A google search for [your specific question] yielded [this](https://example.com) as the first search result."*

Comment: Your sample comment could arguably fall under "_show how googling it would have found the information_", but I don't think ChatGPT has deep linking. With the way you are suggesting to use ChatGPT, it is just a search engine. You'd basically just be telling the OP to go search for help somewhere else. Even if said very gently, it's not really useful to the majority of questions. That said, I probably wouldn't bother flagging a comment like that unless the author was being very rude. Bigger Fish To Fry™