# Should the word "problem" always be blocked from titles?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, title, quality-filter

I'm trying to write a question on Python to be posted on Stack Overflow, and I want to include the phrase "*Pythagorean 3-Body Problem*" in the title, but it's fighting me on it.

[image]

I can understand the intent, but is there, or shouldn't there be an override option? Being pre-emptively censored by a bot without recourse or appeal gives me a bad feeling about the future - reminds me a bit of [Matt Damon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Damon) apologizing to the robot in *[Elysium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_%28film%29)*.

Later, somebody edited the title so that the word now appears!

Comment: Use pr0blem, like a normal person. ;P

Comment: I think you have a point. Not allowing certain words seems too strict. Suggestion might be a better approach. What words are not allowed in titles anyway?

Comment: Speaking of [Python](http://whomovedmyholyhandgrenade.com/Pages/11%20Knights%20of%20Ni.html): *HK: Augh!  Ohh!  Don't say that word., A:  What word?, HK:  I cannot tell, suffice to say is one of the words the Knights of Ni cannot hear., A:  How can we not say the word if you don't tell us what it is?, HK Aaaaugh!*

Comment: [“Problem” word filter can be circumvented in a search engine compatible way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122172/165773)

Comment: To borrow some words: [*While you may be an exemplary, clear-thinking, individual, who uses the term problem in a constructive manner, you have been preceded by a giant procession of zombies who use it as the antithesis of a clear, well formulated question. Thus, the term problem has been rendered an extremely strong signal of an empty resonant cavity in the place where a brain should be, and statements that mention the phrase tend to be closed as the crap they normally are.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/213575)

Comment: And therefore, to make people at least put some thought on writing a better title, we simply block it outright.

Comment: Yep I understand. In this case, it didn't work. It's a proper noun (almost) in this case. This is what it's called by people who do this kind of calculation. It is a well-searched term.

Comment: Use *ProbIem* or *Prοblem* (copy/paste from my comment, this will work) :P

Comment: I actually have the same issue with [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aissue). Although banning *that* will just get people to select [the next in line](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/problem).

Comment: Don't know `Pythagorean 3-Body` but it seems a pretty bad title to me. Like saying `C++ container problem` which is totally useless. Find a more descriptive title that will help others with the same problem to find your question in a search. It must be possible to describe the key words of the problem.

Comment: @StillLearning Sounds like you should look up the 3-body problem, or take note of the comments here indicating that "problem" is *part of the name* of the Pythagorean 3-Body Problem. There is no such thing as "Pythagorean 3-Body."

Comment: Somewhat related: [Ban on the word “problem” for titles makes it difficult to edit existing posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268546/2675154).

Comment: @KyleStrand neither are there [large hadrons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454554/83380) ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from [30th of August 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/1033581), we can now use the word *problem* in titles which are 41 characters or longer.

Comment: And I have been downvoting every misuse of this freedom.

Comment: It is not anybody's job to edit the titles of badly written questions. It is so rarely the case that a good question has a title misusing the word "problem" that downvoting without editing is the best response.

Comment: Problem ...................................................... (this is a title that won't get blocked, but anyways, good change)

Answer (score 58):

> Should the word “problem” always be blocked from titles?

No, you've hit upon one of a relatively small number of cases where it *definitely should* be allowed. Unfortunately, it became a trigger word after it was abused too much by people who were in too much of a hurry to write a descriptive title. We're trying to build up a searchable repository of programming knowledge here, and having thousands of questions with the title [regex problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A+regex+problem) wasn't helping.

> I can understand the intent, but is there, or shouldn't there be an override option?

Yes, there should be! But how should it be implemented? I'd volunteer to edit the very few legitimate uses (like yours) myself, but it's hard to find them in the [tens of thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem) of "problem" search results. We can't really ask moderators or reviewers to wade through the flood of bad titles to pick out only a handful of good ones, so until someone comes up with a way to at least partially automate this process, I'm afraid we're going to be stuck with [lame work-around solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Apr0blem).

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, thanks! It is hard to think of a solution that wouldn't involve some time and effort that could probably be spent better elsewhere - I see what you mean. Maybe a rule-based exception for "the x problem" where x is one or two words that are nouns or noun+adjective that are not "regex", followed by a message asking if the writer really intends on using the word as a proper noun? Ah... explicit special cases is probably just going down a rabbit hole. Anyway, Stackoverflow rocks - actually makes my life better! Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Yes, a whitelist of acceptable terms (knapsack problem, 3-body problem, etc.) is the only workable solution I can think of. A blacklist would probably just grow and grow and end up being a performance/maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Sir, I have a knapsack problem with my code...

Comment: @BoltClock I realize your comment was probably in jest, but in case it was not: I would assume that a majority of questions with "problem" in the title are posed by new users that don't understand how to ask good questions yet. If they see the warning about that word in their title, I'd highly doubt they would think of using a term from a whitelist they don't even know exists in order to get around it.

Comment: There aren't actually that many *regex problems* left like your first search suggests: [title:regex title:problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aregex+title%3Aproblem) and [title:"regex problem"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22regex+problem%22). Having said that, there are still a lot of general [title:problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3aproblem). Also, I myself find that [title:porblem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aporblem) is a much nicer workaround.

Comment: in [fact](http://www.amazon.com/Three-Body-Problem-Mauri-Valtonen/dp/0521852242), [and](http://www.businessinsider.com/mark-zuckerberg-recommends-the-three-body-problem-2015-10) in [fiction](https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102434874214351), in the [news](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2013/03/physicists-discover-whopping-13-new-solutions-three-body-problem), and in [patents](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=pts&hl=en&q=three+body+problem&gws_rd=ssl), I gotta go with zuck because he's rich

Comment: Can I earn a "allowed to use 'Problem' in titles" badge?

Comment: I have the urge to create a programming language called: Problem's pr0blem. >:D

Comment: So it seems that the real problem is that searching for problem is problematic because problem is a popular word to describe a difficult situation. Forcing people to use a thesaurus doesn't fix the search problem, it just changes the problem, and causes confusion for problems like this. Advise people how to write a good question title. Let the bad titles be voted down. Weight "problem" low in the search index. Problem solved.

Comment: @Seth We are not in control of Google's search index.

Comment: Understood. I guess I don't see how disallowing one of the [ten hundred most commonly used words](http://splasho.com/upgoer5/) is going to make much difference in SEO. Surely the same _problem_ exists with the word _issue_, which is not blocked.

Comment: @Seth Just because they're both in the top 1000 doesn't mean they're the same. One could be used 100 times more than the other.

Comment: Ah, now [I see what](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082289/problems-and-questions-regarding-scipy-optimize-minimize-in-python) you are talking about!

Answer (score 25):

I can propose the creation of a new privilege:

> "Allowed to use 'problem' in question titles"

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go as far as making it an official privilege, but I do wonder if silently removing the check for users over X rep might work. Of course, that's assuming that higher rep users automatically know the culture or how to ask questions, which may not hold true.

Comment: hmm... so now I'm wondering what *other* privileges you guys have *already* given yourselves silently :) at least the bot was (perceived to be) "fair" and even-handed. If it were me I'd block users below X, but with a softer message - "sorry, but we've found that new users... the word "problem"...  so ... until you've... I included the screen shot because the big deep red sign "These words are not allowed..." has more of a kick to it than may have been intended.

Comment: @uhoh -- You linked to this answer from another part of the SE network. There are at least two problems here. One is that the people who gain sufficient privileges tend not to ask many questions. Another is that questions about "problems" in computer science can often be posed without using the word "problem". For example, if I was confused about the Byzantine Generals Problem, merely referencing Byzantine generals in the title would more than suffice. OTOH, other stackexchange sites do not ban the word "problem" in titles because they have so many "problems". +1, BTW.

Comment: @DavidHammen if.. you're saying I did something good - thanks, and if bad - sorry! With almost 12 million questions and millions of users, stackoverflow probably *does need* different rules. I think it's this huge size that makes the *vocabulary control bot* an attractive option, not the fact that the subject is computer programming (scientists or not). I'll bet if there was a Perl-only stackexchange, they'd allow themselves to use "problem", "doesn't work", and even "why is my computer always wrong?" :)

Answer (score 4):

So, are we saying the word problem is blocked mostly because we actually think it makes it hard to find good answers to real programming problems??!

Let me rephrase that, is this being blocked because moderators are tired of seeing the word "problem" in the titles of low quality questions, or is there some technical reason of which I am unaware?

**Actual Use:**

1. A Person searches using Google which DOESN'T CARE if the word problem is included but searches for more meaningful words (C++, variables, loop, code, etc...[yes it searches for problem too but, in the statistical average, so what])
2. In their Google results most of what they see will be posts on SO as much because the good ANSWERS have the more valuable technical terms.
3. Finally, the user clicks on an SO link for a question. So long as the question is roughly similar to what they want to know (regardless of specific words) they look through the answers.
4. Finally, (almost ignoring the question) they find a good answer and are happy.

SO, given the above, putting the word problem in the title is only a sin of bad form... a learning point for new users, NOT a major technical issue, (unless of course I am missing something, which sure could be, but then is it a technical weakness to be solved elsewhere or an actual problem?)...

**Before I get flamed for my dissent (though I'm sure I'll get downvoted)**: 
Please let me add that, while to me, allowing the word problem in a title does not seem to be fixing any actual technical problem, or preventing valid users from finding good answers, I think training new users is very important.
As such I suggest something similar to what @BiscuitBaker suggested in his comment to @uhoh 
"...but I do wonder if silently removing the check for users over X rep might work. ...".

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking **I see no *problem* in blocking the word *problem*** ;P. As already outlined in other answers you can always reformulate the question.

To the other hand, **I think that the word *problem* should be permitted** when
is part of the **name** of the Problem.

In such cases it will be always preceded by some other meaningful words and protected by **apices**, exactly as in the question:

> "Pythagorean 3-Body Problem"

or

> "P versus NP problem"

The word *problem* appears as the last word in a sentence protected by **apices**. Is that difficult to implement that in a regexp?

Obviously, a suggestion that specify how to use the word should be included.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A+regex+problem

Comment: *apices*! I just noticed that - are you saying that in a phrase protected by quotes, with "problem" as the last word, it would then be allowed? Sounds great! Should the big red message say "Wait! You forgot your apices you silly goose!"

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, exactly!

Comment: Anything that would allow a title of a question to actually give the name of the subject of the question sounds good to me. Thanks!

Comment: I've moved the "accept" to the [good news](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378279/3904031) answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other nouns that fit and make a usable title, although they obviously won't be found by someone searching for "Problem":

- 3 Body Model
- 3 Body Calculation

The word "Problem" can always be replaced by something more specific.  Whether more specific equated to more descriptive is a bit more problematic, because as you've noted, the best description is the one using the widely accepted term.

Comment: "The word "Problem" can always be replaced by something more specific.", What about the Königsberg Seven Bridge Problem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KoenigsbergBridgeProblem.html or the Travling Salesman Problem?

Comment: @tinkx: "Königsberg Bridge Traversal", "Traveling Salesman Cost Minimization".  As I said in my answer, finding more specific alternatives is not the problem, deviation from the widely used phrase is.

Comment: Those two terms read awkward and incomplete to me. What's missing? The word "problem" you are trying to avoid. Even with what you propose, "Königsberg Bridge Traversal Problem" and "Traveling Salesman Cost Minimization Problem" are still better. Adding the content "Traversal" or "Traversal without repetition" does not help much.

Comment: Probably this is more of an ESL question than a SO one now, so I'll stop from going any further. But the issue with what you propose, I think, is obvious.