# Where are the quality standards for posting questions?

Tags: support, title

Posting a Stack Overflow question I got the error message:

> This title does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it clearly summarizes your problem and uses proper grammar. You can put details in the body of your question.

[image: Error message]

What quality standards are being referred to? That dialog should link to them.

Comment: What was the title you entered?

Comment: I think it used to have a link to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) but I don't think it covers for the *Problem* filter

Comment: The *problem* filter rene is referring to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314712/should-the-word-problem-always-be-blocked-from-titles

Comment: Turns out I just had to use upper case characters in my title.

Comment: @jcarpenter I HOPE YOU DON'T MEAN SOMETHING LIKE THIS!!! ;)

Comment: I know you're joking @ThisSuitIsBlackNot but that title will be allowed ...

Comment: @rene srsly? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: That error message is superimposed directly on top of the How To Ask sidebar, which links to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 6):

The dialog is likely just referring to the information in the Help Center, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular since that page does get into how to write a good title.