# What triggers my title rejection?

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

Trying to improve the title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52097238/107625) ("*kubernetes yaml，error: got “array”, expected “map”*" as of writing) by removing the tags from the title, I gave up frustrated, since every variation I tried is rejected together with a red error message like this one:

> Title cannot contain "Getting data validation error".

While I agree that my suggested title ("*Getting data validation error*") is not the best title in the world, I'm curious how the internal "algorithm" to reject a title is implemented.

Searching here through Meta with "Title cannot contain" revealed no meaningful results, I'm trying to ask here.

Some of the titles I've tried unsuccessfully were:

- `Getting error: Got array, expected map`.
- `Getting data validation error`.
- `Error got array, expected map`.

**My question:**

Which criteria are being used to reject a question's title?

Comment: It is a regex ...

Comment: @rene with which pattern?

Comment: @UweKeim I would love to know but this is all I have for now https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5645581#5645581 but IIRC mods can see the regexes that are currently used.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulWhite. I've just tried `Getting error: Got array, expected map` and it gets rejected, too.

Comment: Well, not _every_ title suggestion is being blocked- I just submitted a suggested edit (there were grammatical errors I wanted to fix too) and managed to submit with a more descriptive title.

Comment: To be fair, those title "improvements" are not very descriptive of the problem.  Even though that's the exact verbatim error message, those title don't even try to describe the context for the error.  Compare this to Kendra's edit which includes some context or explanation for why this error is unusual.

Comment: By the way, if you're going to edit the post, please get as many of the errors as you can at the same time- You're so focused on the title you're missing very obvious grammatical errors and one of your minor changes just rejected mine _with_ a better title: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20729017

Comment: None of those are questions. What's the actual question? "How do I fix a "got 'array', expected 'map'" ValidationError"? "How do I do {whatever this code is trying to do}"? (The question in the body asks why they're getting it, but I suppose that means they want to know how to fix it)

Comment: @Dukeling the title doesn't strictly _have_ to be a question, it just has to be descriptive and actually help people understand at a glance what the problem is. (Which none of those examples really do, either.)

Comment: @Kendra Sure, but usually some phrasing of what the user actually wants to know makes for a good title.

Comment: "How do I fix a data validation error?"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Judging by the regex on [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388) to [Allow "question" in title if enclosed in quotation marks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373209), the issue is two-fold: You've got a short title with "error" in it.

That's it. I'm a little rusty on my regex, but this seems straightforward, so let me try to break it down a hair:

```
^(?=.{0,40}$)(?=.*\b(question(?!\s+mark)|doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|(?<!(visual studio|vs|exit)\s+)code|my)\b).+
```

So the first part:

```
^(?=.{0,40}$)
```

Looks to see if the string is 40 characters long. `^` looks for the start of string, `$` looks for the end, and `.{0,40}` looks for any character up to forty characters.

If the string is longer than 40 characters, the regex will fail to match right here.

If not, we move on to the next bit:

```
(?=.*\b(question(?!\s+mark)|doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|(?<!(visual studio|vs|exit)\s+)code|my)\b)
```

This is a bit long, but it's looking for something specific: Any of those words at any point in the string. It's a look around just to see if it exists. It's not actually part of the capture, just part of the match. As of September 11th, it actively excludes Visual Studio code, VS code, and exit code.

The last part is what, I presume, is grabbing the title to throw to the error message.

While the error message is not descriptive, this does explain why my suggested title with my suggested edit works, while your attempts do not, though they all contain "error": My suggested title is more descriptive and therefore longer.

That's it. Keep in mind this is supposed to encourage more descriptive titles, and the ones you've suggested.... Really aren't. They're very generic. All I know going in is that something's expecting an array and getting a map, which is throwing an error. Why is this error unexpected? What's unusual about it? Why not just give whatever a map instead of an array?

Meanwhile, the one I suggested, both in my conflicted edit and my newest suggestion on that question:

> Received error about getting “array” and expecting “map” while my yaml seems right

This (tries to, at least, not my area of expertise) explains why it's weird: The yaml seems to be right, so it shouldn't get an error. Everything looks to be correct, passing the correct things... So the OP doesn't understand why it's wrong.

---

This also, upon further investigation (as in just checking string length) explains how the original title was able to get through: It's 50 characters.

Comment: Although I haven't encountered this particular error message personally, as I usually have the opposite problem when trying to come up with a title (too long and unfocused XD), do you think its wording could be confusing to a new question poster?  Specifically, the way it says "Title cannot contain XYZ" where XYZ is the entire (proposed) title OP intends to use.  Doesn't **contain** in this context imply that it's the entire sequence taken as a whole that's somehow problematic, instead of the one or two keywords (like 'error' here) that are actually triggering the rejection?

Answer (score 45):

### "[The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so)"

But let's give it an history:

- At some point in 2011, the following words got banned from question titles (of any length):

  - "**question**"
  - "**doubt**"
  - "**problem**"
- Later, "**question mark**" got allowed as an exception to the rule.
- [On 30th August 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/1033581), the list filter got **limited to question titles between 15-40 characters**, but extended to forbid all those words as well (was also added word "**can**", but it got removed less than two weeks later):

  - "**working**"
  - "**work**"
  - "**app**"
  - "**error**"
  - "**website**"
  - "**code**"
  - "**my**"
- [On 11th September 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373958/1033581), "**visual studio code**", "**vs code**" and "**exit code**" got allowed as exceptions to the rule.

Those are very generic words, especially for programmers, so it's not at all obvious to decipher the error message:

> Please provide a title that summarizes your question.

Seeing the list of offending vocabulary, **the easiest course of action is to make your title at least 41 characters long**. Of course, improving your title to avoid those words is often preferred.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy I came to somewhat accept it with the time. Shog9 maybe did something that was required to stop the flow of poor titles.

Comment: I can't even edit my own question anymore. I wanted to drop the JSON tag, as the question has actually nothing to do with JSON. I can't, because the title contains the word "error'. Maybe I could try to make the title less relevant in order to pass the test? I won't, but you see where this is going... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348018/list-of-facebook-error-codes/56260479#56260479

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy in the extreme case, there are some 0-width unicode characters... but that feels like the cure is worse than the disease. I got no idea on how to improve the title of your Question. Maybe worth asking specifically on Meta. A similar issue exists with the title of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603218/three-egg-problem

Comment: **"app"**... how ridiculous.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you feel that there isn't any ambiguity in what "not working" mean. For example, `print` means display text. Then if `print` doesn't work, the only way to interpret "not working" is that there is no text being displayed even though there is `print`.

However, even in `print`, there are differences into whether it's expected to append a terminating line ending, where the text is displayed, and what sort of string is expected. So it's very easy for someone primary experienced in a different language to get confused about what working means for a specific variant of `print`.

<sub>Kudo to [@user1937198](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/why-does-this-title-bad-why-does-xxx-not-working?noredirect=1#comment781973_399332)</sub>

Comment: Even then, "not working" for `print` could just as easily mean that an exception is raised.