# Trying to ask a question about running C/C++ code from CosmosOS but it thinks that I want to run C from C#

Tags: support, asking-questions, title, quality-filter

I'm am developing a basic OS using CosmosOS devkit, and I have a question:

```
Title: CosmosOS - Run C/C++ code from kernel
Tags: c# cosmos c c++
============================================

Hello, I am making a basic OS with CosmosOS kernel. I want to make the CosmosOS a bootloader, and other will be C/C++. 

Is it possible to run C/C++ executables (.exe) or run it in any other way using CosmosOS?
```

But the "question improvenent system" thinks that I am asking for running C from C# (without CosmosOS stuff):

```
Title cannot contain "CosmosOS - Run C/C++ code from kernel".

Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?
========================================================================================================
And in similar questions:
run C code from C# (have one downvote)
```

When I add "C#" into the title, it additionally says:

> Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements. Consider updating your question title and body to be more descriptive

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What triggers my title rejection?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection)

Comment: Laurel, yes, thanks. I just added "the kernel" and it worked.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with [C#] if it doesn't have anything to do with C#?

Comment: actually it has, beacuse cosmosos is a c# os devkit