# I would like to be able to edit questions without correcting issues with the title

Tags: feature-request, title, word-filter

This isn't the first time I've bumped up against this, but its been enough times that I'm starting to grind my teeth about it.

I just made this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52087928/3

The system informed me that the question's original title was not allowed, despite the fact that:

1. I was making an edit
2. I hadn't changed it

I get that the title's "banned" for one reason or another, but don't *force* me as an editor to fix it! It got migrated in or some other way bypassed the filters and all I want to do is fix up the image in the post so it isn't flocking huge! Fortunately I was able to minorly modify the title (adding "do") in order to bypass.

The last time I ran into this, I couldn't do that. The thread title was a copy-paste of an error message, had gotten migrated, so there were *three* questions that already existed with that title (*none* of which solved the user's problem!) and any modifications I could make that wouldn't detrimentally affect the title *had already been questions too!* (of which none solved the user's problem). I did not know how to edit the title that left it descriptive of the problem at hand and gave up (I may have left a comment on the question, but I can not find it).

Can we change this, please? If it warns me at least give me the option to bypass the warning. By canceling the edit (if I decide the other improvements aren't worth it), *the title remains bad anyway.*

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/792066

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection

Answer (score 10):

Nobody's forcing you to fix anything.

But if you're gonna fix it... Try & actually make the author look good:

[image: numerous additional edits to the title and body to add readability and ensure consistency in writing style]

Comment: Maybe if we had stronger incentives to fix the post, like, I don't know. Make it clear that any improvement on the post is welcomed.

Comment: I don't know what your incentive is. Mine is to make the post easier to read, easier to find, and easier to understand. And that starts with a descriptive title.

Comment: Oh great Shog, the other image you cropped you made included all the white space that I was cropping out of the first one! Also, I do fix what I see most of the time. In this case was looking out only for the giant image that needed to be less giant (there was so much white against white that it looked like the page ended: the rest of the question was so far down that it was off my screen) and wanted to be on my way.

Comment: The image I cropped included not only the whitespace but the entire window and margins surrounding that whitespace. I don't care about the whitespace so much as I wanted to be able to actually see the important part of the image (yes, I suppose it is appropriate that scaling broke a question about scaling breaking an app). Anyway; it took me far longer to fix all the minor issues with the post and write alt-text for the images than it did to write a title. If you had to stop short, fixing the images (both of them...) and the title would've sufficed.

Comment: PS: if you do crop the image further, maybe fix that "m" that should've been an 'n' that I overlooked?