# Title cannot contain "How to build XXX in VS Code?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, title, content-blocklist

Since introduction of some regex limiting the titles, I can't ask the question about Visual Studio Code in the title.

> Title cannot contain "How to build X in VS Code?".

I was struggling to understand why my title is rejected and narrowed it down to the "Code" word.

The limitation of "code" word doesn't make sense for me.

Related: [Allow "question" in title if enclosed in quotation marks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373209/55075)

Comment: Might not make sense, but if you manage to wordify your title a little more, make it 41+ characters... Well, the regex won't worry about "code" anymore. (Not an answer since _you_ probably realize the work around, and it doesn't answer why "code" is in the filter.)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about 41+ character rule, that solved the issue. Shouldn't then the message be more clearer (like, the title is too short)?

Comment: 100% should be clearer, totally agree. I have a pretty good breakdown of the regex in my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection/373418#373418) btw.

Comment: Easy fix: do not put tags in titles. Use the VS Code tag and it will be found anyway

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Easy, but severely inadequate: titles must be globally unique, so whenever there's already a question with the same title but asked about something other than VS Code, you have problems.

Comment: See also [this answer that breaks down exactly what words are not allowed in question titles in what conditions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373459)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gotta love branding that co-opts generic words... In titles, "code" is the hallmark of terrible stuff like,

- program code
- to create mysqli code for this statement
- code not working as intended
- Interrupt code?
- VBA CODE IS NOT WORKING FOR <> NOT EQUAL

(all actual attempted titles from the past day)

Worth noting here that the problem isn't the word "code", or even the length of the title - those are just heuristics. These are bad titles because *they don't tell you anything interesting about the problem!* The solution isn't "pad it out to 41 characters" or "munge the word c0de", it's "write a title that describes the problem" - so that's what I ask folks to do!

...However, there are some common terms that also contain "code" but have a meaning that's specific enough to be useful in even a very short title:

- Visual Studio Code
- VS Code
- exit code

So, I've updated the block to exempt these:

```
^(?=.{0,40}$)(?=.*\b(question(?!\s+mark)|doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|(?<!(visual studio|vs|exit)\s+)code|my)\b).+
```

Comment: That regex is *so* inefficient. Replace the match logic with something better like `title.length > 40 || match(/\b(...)\b/)`; it's so much clearer and probably faster too.

Comment: At that point it's not just a regex, which means I need to redesign the validation system this feeds into. Which might be worth doing... But that's a 6-8 week thing. And, notably, no one actually did it in the ~7 years folks were complaining about the previous title validation regex, so... Lesser evil, IMHO. titles are hard limited to, what, a couple hundred characters? Gotta be a limit to how much that lookahead can really hurt.

Comment: @Shog9 how about 'code snippet'?  Because I can't ask a question titled: 'Change literal in code snippet' about how to change the literal value when creating a code snippet in VS

Comment: "Change a literal's value when creating a code snippet in Visual Studio" works just fine and is probably a more descriptive title, @mcalex

Comment: Dear @Shog9, thank you for those sane rules. May we also have the word **help** moved to this regex in order to allow "**help**" on long title (more than 40 chars)? Otherwise, with the current indiscriminate blocking of this word, people are substituing it for Cyrillic characters like in [Hеlp-button in a message box not working in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168265/h%D0%B5lp-button-in-a-message-box-not-working-in-a-console-application). Thank you.

Comment: *"... branding that co-opts generic words"*. *[word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word)* comes to mind.

Comment: *ASCII code*, perhaps?

Comment: I'm dragged in with `code folding` and also `source code` is barred too.

Comment: http-status-code

Comment: Reminder to folks reading this: you can use all of these words in your titles, you just need to use other words along with 'em. They're only blocked if you're DETERMINED to use an embarrassingly short title that forces readers to click through to figure out what you're actually asking about. So, y'know... **Don't write click-bait!**

Comment: @Shog9 feature-request: please add "QR code" to your whitelist, as [it's a trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) and currently [2,145 questions use it in their title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22qr+code%22). Thank you.

Comment: This is preventing me from editing "Code completion in enums for Eclipse?" Too bad they purged you so you can't fix it. Seems like grandfathering in old question titles would be a good idea.

Comment: @Shog9 can you please add "Xcode"?

Comment: Afraid not, @pkamb - don't work here anymore. But someone can! Post a new request and someone should see it.

Comment: Can you guys exclude the phrase `source code`? Not everything with the `code` is bad. See this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417431/how-do-i-re-phrase-the-title-to-better-summarize-the-question#417431

Comment: To me "Code behind" looks like an other thing that needs to be exempted from the bad tittle hammer