# Rep cap on the title restriction

Tags: feature-request, questions

So apparently there's a filter on certain question titles as stated in [Shogs answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373958/1870760). I was trying to write a question with the word "code" in it and I wasn't allowed to.

Can we please disable the question title block for users that have more than x rep? I would expect that these members know how to write a proper question anyway.

Comment: If this is implemented, can you add `[SOLVED]` to your title?

Comment: @usr2564301 What am I missing?

Comment: Is there *really* no way you can avoid the word "code" in your title?  Like, really??

Comment: What title are you trying to use that contains the word "code"? Providing an example of why it is needed will help with your case.

Answer (score 2):

No. Will likely cause more confusion than do good.

- there is no proven correlation between reputation and "know how to write proper …"
- having different restrictions on posts depending on reputation will essentially block people from editing posts. We already have cases where some users can't update posts due to "too much code" and regex restrictions changing over time. I don't see explicitly adding one to be that useful.
- spending couple extra minutes on re-wording title is good anyway :)

Note: as you brough up in the question for particular cases you may bring regex filter up for discussion and filters may be improved for everyone - i.e. "VS Code" - [Title cannot contain "How to build XXX in VS Code?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373956/title-cannot-contain-how-to-build-xxx-in-vs-code?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: `there is no proven correlation between reputation and "know how to write proper …"` Actually there is, but I that's still no reason to exclude users from the requirement of a decent title.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Proven? Really? I'd like to see that study.

Comment: @DavyM knowing how to write properly is vague enough that I could practically define it around creating a correlation with rep. My point is, the presence or absence of a correlation doesn't matter because there are still those few high-rep users who **don't** know.

Comment: @StephenLeppik it matter for Sombrero Chicken - so I added it a reason. If you have any link to reasonably study - I'd happy to update the post (or feel free to edit one in).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'll make one myself, just after I get a refresher on SQL aggregate functions.

Comment: @StephenLeppik A proven correlation means that we can confidently say "X leads to Y." Just showing that "When there's more X, there tends to be more Y" is not nearly enough to be a proof. Though I could point you towards some [tools](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/) that you can use to construct a statistical justification for your claim, and if you do that, I will find your results interesting. But I was pointing out your claim that there already exists one proven, I didn't understand you to say you would create one.

Comment: @DavyM I think you're misunderstanding what a "correlation" means.

Comment: @StephenLeppik That's a rather useless thing to say without providing your own explanation of what you believe correlation actually means and why that doesn't fit with my use of the word. And I'm not predisposed to believe you as you have already claimed that a proven correlation exists when that proof clearly has not been created yet, given that you admitted you needed to make one yourself.

Comment: @DavyM quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence): "In the broadest sense **correlation** is any statistical association, though in common usage it most often refers to how close two variables are to having a [linear relationship](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) with each other." In other words, "When there's more X, there tends to be more Y". Your other one, "X leads to Y", would be *causation*, which requires a controlled trial.

Comment: @StephenLeppik You're missing out on the word "Proven" from all of that. Just showing that "When there's more X, there tends to be more Y" is showing a correlation. Proving the correlation takes more work, and even so, you only show that one thing leads to another. You don't prove that one thing causes another, you prove that a relation exists. A proven correlation is done by showing that the difference between the observed results amd the expected results are statistically significant.

Comment: It's the difference between taking an SQL sample of data showing x% of new users use bad titles and y% of high rep users  do as well, and saying "y < x," which is just a correlation, compared to proving that the difference between y and x is large enough to matter. And even though now you've possibly proven the correlation that one leads to the other, you still haven't proven that one causes the other.

Comment: Anyways, sorry @AlexeiLevenkov, I'll stop filling your answer with comments.

Comment: @DavyM yeah, we should stop bickering about how a term is defined. (Besides, it's fun trying to make a SEDE query for it.)