# What makes a question automatically forbidden by the system?

Tags: discussion, questions, bad-questions

I have recently tried to ask a question and the title I typed was rejected by the system, showing a message like this:

[image: Forbidden question]

I'm wondering what is the rule behind? Is there some machine learning tuned to detect bad questions based on their pattern?

Comment: Indepently on the particular heuristics to detect bad titles in general; the specific title you were trying to use is as poor as it can be. Your title should attempt to describe your problem so that a user reading the title can get at least a general idea about the issue you have. _"I have problems. Hlep!!"_ doesn't describe anything. Writing a good title is not easy, but the effort is worthwhile.

Comment: Not 100% sure, so not leaving an answer, but I'm pretty sure it is just a RegEx with some common phrases and words that make up bad titles.

Comment: This is not the title I actually tried, just for the sake of example. I know what makes a good title but I wonder if there are some specific rules?

Comment: Highly related/possible duplicate, I'll leave that for others to decide because I'm on the fence about it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection/373418#373418

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no machine learning behind it. It's just a regular expression.

You can find a part of the regular expression [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373958/7296893), plus an explanation why *code* in combination with a short title usually leads to trouble.

The rules are purposefully not listed to encourage users to follow guidance on how to write a proper title, instead of allowing them to bypass the rules.

Comment: "Proper title" is a bit strong of a phrase...