# Why is this error message so ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was asking a question, and found this error message:
[image: Title cannot contain "Floating Point Error - Numpy"]

The issue was actually just the word "error" which I was able to find out because of [Title cannot contain "How to build XXX in VS Code?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373956/title-cannot-contain-how-to-build-xxx-in-vs-code). It seems the regex title system does not like certain words. That is fair, and I am fine restructuring my title to avoid words. But that error message is useless.

New users asking questions aren't malicious. You don't need to hide information from them, they are just ignorant. Perhaps a  better designed error message is

> The word 'error' often leads to ambiguous question titles that do not fully address your problem. Try a more descriptive word or phrase. See: how to ask

This makes it much more clear to me, an at least somewhat experienced asker, that I should try a different word and be more descriptive, while providing the same helpful feedback to a new user.

Should the first error message be changed, or is there a reason for it being so confusing?

Comment: "Oh they won't let me put the word error? Haha, I'll put 3rror and get around the filter!" We prefer people to go out searching how to make a good title, not how to get around the filter. The question you linked explains in detail why these trigger words were chosen for the filter.

Comment: *"I am fine restructuring my title to avoid words"* This is going to give me nightmares about titles that contain only emojis, with no words.

Comment: Me too, but mostly because I've already investigated blocking emoji-only titles and the regex involved is nightmarish

Comment: @CodyGray Oh come on, you know what I meant.

Comment: Oh, absolutely I knew what you meant. But I never pass up an opportunity to make a joke. This was especially fortuitous because of the recent discussions on Meta about emojis. Besides, in all fairness, the amusing reading was actually my first reading. Anyway, I agree with both sides here. I know the rationale presented by Servy and Tim, and I almost wholeheartedly agree with it. Yet, I also agree with you that the error message is subpar. I'd tweak it slightly, if I could, to emphasize that the title was not descriptive enough and needed to be rewritten, but still not focus on blocked words.

Comment: The word "problem" is blocked, users typically fall back to "pr0blem".  Works here as well, it is an err0r.

Answer (score 11):

These words and phrases aren't inherently problematic, they're simply accurate indicators of problematic content.  The goal is not to get people to remove the word that is a red flag, it's to get people to actually *fix the problem that the word is indicative of*.

You did exactly what we *don't* want people to do.  You just used a synonym for one of the flagged words.  What you *should* have done was edit your title to *actually describe the problem you're having*, rather than having a title so vague it's just saying *that* you have a problem.  Don't tell us that you're having some kind of error (or use the word "issue" because "error" is a red flag for the system that you have a poor title),  *tell us what the error is*.

This is all explained in detail in the linked help center article as well.

Comment: This is probably controversial, but how many "floating point errors/issues" are there? I guess I could have added the word rounding somewhere in there, but I felt that floating point issue implied a rounding issue. The word approximation should also help point to the issue. What title would you recommend? I would be happy to replace.

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises If you think your question is no different than every other floating point rounding related question out there then *why are you even asking your question*?  Given that *you* apparently think it's not a unique question?  Reading your question it's not actually clear what your problem is, and what you're asking for, so as the entire question is unclear, I couldn't suggest a title that accurately represents that question.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. It really clarified what you said. I could not find a question/answer that would help me, or any online resources, so I asked a new question. In my comment, I was asking why "floating point approximation issue" did not describe my issue fully. If I understand your comment correctly, you said it was because my issue was at least somewhat clear, but what I wanted as a solution was not? Did I understand your comment correctly?

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises When I said your question was unclear I meant that your question was unclear, not that it was clear.  What is your actual question?  Are you wondering why the variable isn't representing the value exactly?  Because there are a million floating point number questions out there answering that, and it's just a duplicate.  If you have some more specific question, I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @Warp cynically, your question seems to be 'I understand floating points inaccuracy and how they add up over time. But .. can someone explain to me how it works and how to make sure they DON'T add up over time?'.  I personally think your question is clear: it's a clear dupe of other floating point arithmetic question. If you need *more*.... That's the piece that's unclear (to me)

Comment: @Patrice That's actually quite fair. I just want my 1 trig function to come out correct. The reason I want it to come out correct is so that it doesn't add up, but that's the justification for the question, not the question. Yes, that might be a dupe of other questions/answers, but nothing I saw and tried resolved my issue. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 6):

Servy's answer is correct. And, until we make much bigger strides into finding ways to help people write better titles, it's pretty much the best we're going to do.

What we'd *like* to provide is a title strength indication, sort of similar to password strength, that goes up as you write a better title. That would mean "Problem with android" or all emoji or ALL CAPS ALL THE TIME and titles that lack anything other than common words would show as weak, as expressed by an indicator describing how likely your question will be to be answered, or even noticed and read.

Predictive analysis helps here *some* but it's still really tag-specific as far as associating characteristics of title with post score, views, number and length of answers, and so on. Coming up with this system and just mandating that titles must be "of medium strength or better" for something to post is probably inevitable, but *really* harder than it seems on the surface.

So, yes, the message *could* be better at not triggering someone to just see which words tripped a regex filter, but I think efforts at getting rid of the regex filter altogether in favor of something smarter would be better.

Answer (score 6):

It's vague because they don't want people to try to game the filter. I suggest that you write a better title for your question; "Floating Point Error - Numpy" is *very* vague and non-descriptive, and the current question title isn't much better. You should describe what the actual problem is.