# What do we expect users to do when the quality filter rejects their title?

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

I am attempting to ask a question about what the replacement mechanism is for Apple's now-deprecated System Settings bundles for tvOS applications. In doing so, I had a bit of difficulty coming up with a title that was acceptable.

Some examples:

[image: The error produced for the suggested title "System Settings for my app"]

[image: The error produced for the suggested title "System Preferences for my app"]

[image: The error produced for the suggested title "How to create System Settings for my app"]

I suspect that the phrase "system settings" is often used in titles of off-topic questions and we're trying to avoid creating more of those. It wasn't until the 3rd one  that I received a pop-up explaining that. Regardless, "System Settings" is the name Apple gives (or possibly gave - I still haven't found an answer) to the place where applications are supposed to put additional settings for the user to change.  It's sometimes called "System Preferences".

It eventually accepted ["Additional settings to display in System Settings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318961/additional-settings-to-display-in-system-settings) It took me about 5-6 tries to come up with that. What do we expect users to do when the question they're asking requires a phrase that has previously caused questions to get downvoted?

Comment: How about if you say that it's your app for tvOS? Every app has some kind of system settings. BTW, stating that the bundle isn't available anymore in your title may help.

Comment: I thought it was generally discouraged to use tags in the titles of posts, so I was trying to avoid that pitfall.

Comment: What is discouraged is using the [tag]: sentence or tag- sentence or sentence - [tag][tag] structure. If the word fits organically to give it a whole sense to the question, then just use it.

Comment: App is one of the disallowed words in titles, because the grand majority of questions that are asked with the word app tend to be too broad or off topic. Shog has a  copy of the regex available for viewing [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/7795130). The words "doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|can|code|my" are all blocked on questions shorter than 40 characters.

Comment: That's funny, "How to create system settings for my app" is exactly 40 characters, so if you had just added a question mark, it would have gone through.

Comment: Haha! Well, live and learn, I guess!

Comment: Should really be worded as a question...

Comment: Why don't you just ask the question *that you wrote in the first sentence of this question*? "Is there a replacement mechanism for Apple's now-deprecated System Settings bundles for tvOS applications?" is perfectly acceptable, both by the rules and the "Ask a Question" screen.

Comment: Meta.SE FAQ on how to write a good title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title (that would by-and-large solve the issue of having a title rejected)

Comment: Make a big enough stink on Twitter about how SO is hostile and won't let them ask for help that management makes a series of controversial unilateral changes?

Comment: related: [What triggers my title rejection?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What do we expect users to do when the question they're asking requires a phrase that has previously caused questions to get downvoted?

You're close. It's not that they get downvoted, it's that they get downvoted and then *closed and/or deleted*, which creates [other problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). In fact, the system helped you a great deal because

> System Settings for my app

sounds like a terrible question for SO. Why? Because, it sounds like you're trying to get [support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) for a phone/device app.

I noted that you even improved upon the one in your Meta question (which still wasn't great) and went with

> What template can I use for a tvOS app system settings, since it's not included anymore?

To say that this is *worlds* better would be an understatement. It's abundantly clear from this title that you're asking a programming question, not a technical support one, which leads me to the ultimate point here:

## The system prevented you from making a terrible mistake.

What we're expecting is that you're going to go "Why can't I ask this question using my simple title?" and then **make a better title**. Speaking from [experience with tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym), nobody reads warnings, so the system just won't let you make an easy mistake. Yes, you can [drive around the crossing guards](https://youtu.be/ehXMXvvO-Wc?t=76), but not having them at all would let people make a mistake without forcing them to read *any* warnings at all.

Comment: Note about the new title, I'm not an expert on said technology, I just used the keywords that the question were using and reordered into a sentence about what seemed to be the issue.