# Why does Stack Overflow think this question title isn't valid?

Tags: support, asking-questions, title, quality-filter, specific-edit

I wanted to edit this [question title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56156183/1244884) to make it more generic and got this confusing error message:

> Title cannot contain "Object.keys doesn't work with DOM nodes".

[image]

However the following title is valid:

```
Object.keys doesn't work with `DOM nodes`
```

It seems like quoting `DOM nodes` with back ticks made a difference but why?

Comment: It's probably the "doesn't work".

Comment: But why is the second version of the title (the one with back ticks around `DOM nodes`) acceptable then?

Comment: Perhaps it's weighted (so certain number of negative characters/words aren't allowed) and maybe the back ticks push it to the positive side?

Comment: On a Q&A site, the words `doesn't work` are likely to be used in a question though. There are about [± 500K questions](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22doesn%27t+work%22) with those words in their title. Perhaps high quality questions tend to not have those in their title, but weighting them down seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: Shog has a copy of the regex available for viewing [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/7795130). The words "doubt|problem|working|work|app|error|website|can|code|my" are all blocked on questions shorter than 40 characters. With the backticks, it was 41 characters, thus avoiding the regex.

Comment: What I commented is completely covered by the duplicate, so I say you should accept the duplicate.

Comment: @DavyM Sorry that's not what I meant. No need to post an answer; I accept your comment as an answer. I already accepted the linked question and also voted to close my own question too. I could delete it but *maybe* it's still useful to leave it here.