# Is "get rid of" regarded as a bad phrase?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

If I have a question with the title "Get rid of override reason for TFS", I get the message "Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements."

However, if I use "Remove override reason for TFS", I don't get the message.

Is "Get rid of" regarded as unprofessional or n00bish? Or does it make its title similar to a specific question that was poorly received?

Comment: Gonna be honest, I wouldn't put much weight - if any - into those heuristics. It very likely did a search (and SO is notoriously bad for searching) which ended up matching with badly scored questions.

Comment: This is clearly a machine-generated heuristic. It's not like a human sat down and typed out a list of phrases, so I don't think you're going to get an answer that provides a solid, logical rationale for the warning generated here.

Comment: In this case, maybe someone who has the privileges to search for deleted questions with a similar title would be able to help.

Comment: Also related, the [problem problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314712/should-the-word-problem-always-be-blocked-from-titles) which isn't even a heuristic... but still demonstrates the *problem* with trusting these warnings too much. As for your question about deleted questions, there are 2,162 deleted questions with "Get rid of" in the title, and 6,764 questions which are not deleted (6,376 of which aren't closed either)

Comment: got this advice from the bot on most of my upvoted questions. get rid of the message and do your best in question body

Comment: @Rob Could you make the same with "remove"? Maybe "get rid of" still has a higher proportion of deleted questions. It's surely a bit more colloquial, not that this is a bad thing per se.

Comment: @Trilarion Deleted: 38,608. Undeleted: 146,136. Undeleted & Open: 137,950. Note that there's a bunch of deleted questions which were vandalized to titles like 'Please remove'

Comment: @Rob Seems to be roughly a ratio of 1 : 3 for deleted : undeleted, independent of the phrase.

Comment: I've seen that warning on several question titles I've posted that were nevertheless well-received. If you have a history of posting good questions, it's safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Folks looking to "get rid of" something are often asking about a warning, error, artifacts of undefined behavior, unterminated strings and other things where they didn't *quite* understand the scope of the problem they were seeing. In those cases, questions tend to be pretty terse and written from a tragically fragile but confident perspective (as in "Okay, now all I have to do is get rid of [thing] ...")

It's a warning. And to the initiated scholar, it's *probably* safe to ignore without peril (or a bunch of jeers and downvotes).

Answer (score -15):

**get rid of** isn't bad phrase, as sometimes we just get bored or irritate of something that may be any object or human or an animal. So here we can use **get rid of**, lets take an example that you are just **tired and got irritate of your bike that is giving you anger every time you drive because of its maintainance**, so now you want to sell this and just become relax in this situation you will use **get rid of this bike and buy a new one**.

Hope this example makes you smile and also satisfy your question

Comment: Do keep in mind that the OP was asking about this phrase as it relates to Stack Overflow and more specifically about a warning message that they received when trying to post a question that had that phrase in the title.  It is not about the general usage of this phrase, which apppears to be what you are trying to answer here