# How does SO automatically detect bad questions?

Tags: support, bad-questions

While I was composing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739516/what-is-the-special-meaning-of-parentheses-in-uris) a notification appeared that said the following:

> Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements. Consider updating your question title and body to be more descriptive

I've never seen this before, and while I can understand that a question phrased along the lines of "What if the meaning of..." is probably a bad question, I don't understand how SO could have decided this automatically.

So, my question is, under what circumstances does the following notification appear?

[image: Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements]

Comment: Looks like it's detected exactly on the criteria mentioned. The similarity of the title text, and the community's negative feedback score on these.

Comment: This may help: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/)

Comment: Kind of related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393953/is-get-rid-of-regarded-as-a-bad-phrase

Comment: So, it told you it was a bad question, and you posted it anyway?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But OP is asking what constitutes "similar".

Comment: @HereticMonkey: What's the problem with that? OP took it under advisement and decided the question merited posting.

Comment: @einpoklum I suspect some trained full text search module like _lucene_ or such, will define what _similarity_ means in this context.

Comment: @einpoklum I have no problem with it. Considering the OP's own assessment of the message as saying the question is "bad", I was surprised.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ok, but OP is asking for something more specific they so they know what to avoid.

Comment: I'd just like to add that, although I believe my question is not bad at all, it has now been closed. I have voted to reopen it. Meanwhile, this very similar question has 36 upvotes and some excellent answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163803/what-is-the-semicolon-reserved-for-in-urls

Comment: Note the difference in phrasing and subject, though. The question with many upvotes asks a specific question about a specific character in a specific RFC. The question that was closed and reopened asks about subjective commentary about an RFC made on a different site. I suggest rephrasing the question more along the lines of the upvoted one: "What are the parentheses reserved for in a URL?" Quote the relevant portion of the RFC, and ask for facts, not supposition. Leave the Wikipedia article out of it.

Comment: Very poorly is the correct answer

Comment: @hedgie unlike the other question, yours has been and still is asking for arbitrary examples. Seeing how URIs are used with tons of schemas, many of which are custom, it is effectively asking for an open list. That is a completely different scope than that of the“similar“ question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's intentionally undocumented what the precise heuristics are for this message. Documenting heuristics like this makes them nearly useless.

The message is merely advisory. You're supposed to see it, consider whether your question is, in fact, one that might be poorly received, and use that to decide whether or not to go through with posting it.

Comment: Thanks! I still have no idea why my question was poorly received, but SO's artifical intelligence surely predicted it correctly. Perhaps the phrasing implied I was looking for subjective commentary in some way?

Comment: I think MisterMiyagi aptly noted the issues with your question in a comment above. The edit you just submitted looks like an improvement to me.