# Can we please remove the "Title cannot contain" restriction for users with full edit privileges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, edits

I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652492/how-does-the-operator-work-in-c) today to remove some of the unneeded fluff at the end.

However, I was restricted because of the title's content, and got this message:

[image]

This is frustrating when I try to improve old questions, and this specific title suits this question perfectly.

Can we *please* remove this restriction for users with full edit privileges?

Comment: I once had a [similar _problem_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268546/2675154).

Comment: If the title is considered bad when posting a question why should it be allowed after the fact when editing a question? Seems like an easy way to get around the various title restrictions if they can be avoided when editing a question.

Comment: There ought to be an exception mechanism for this. We can call it *edit grandfathering*. And rate-limited to one per day. And perhaps with badge (e.g. [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67402#67402)) and reputation points requirements.

Comment: @JoeW It was just a reputation requirement (not an edit thing). At 2000 rep, users ought to know what a good title and a bad title are.

Comment: It's also a problem when the question-title is actually perfectly fine, but contains certain proper-nouns that SO thinks are generic words (e.g. "code" in "VS Code").